# Regular expression that matches valid IPv6 addresses

Tags: regex, networking, ipv6

I'm having trouble writing a regular expression that matches valid IPv6 addresses, including those in their compressed form (with `::` or leading zeros omitted from each byte pair).

Can someone suggest a regular expression that would fulfill the requirement?

I'm considering expanding each byte pair and matching the result with a simpler regex.

Comment: Check out http://www.intermapper.com/ipv6validator.. it links to this [perl test script](http://download.dartware.com/thirdparty/test-ipv6-regex.pl)

Comment: I have tried all of the answers below and they do not work for all my test cases and/or they also include IPv4 which wasn't asked for.  I have found this to be the cleanest solution so far: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21944928/3112803

Answer (score 323):

I was unable to get @Factor Mystic's answer to work with POSIX regular expressions, so I wrote one that works with POSIX regular expressions and PERL regular expressions.

It should match:

- IPv6 addresses
- zero compressed IPv6 addresses ([section 2.2 of rfc5952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5952#section-2.2))
- link-local IPv6 addresses with zone index ([section 11 of rfc4007](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4007#section-11))
- IPv4-Embedded IPv6 Address ([section 2 of rfc6052](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6052#section-2))
- IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses ([section 2.1 of rfc2765](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2765#section-2.1))
- IPv4-translated addresses  ([section 2.1 of rfc2765](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2765#section-2.1))

IPv6 Regular Expression:

```
(([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){7,7}[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,7}:|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,6}:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,5}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,2}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,3}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,3}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,2}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,5}|[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:((:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,6})|:((:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,7}|:)|fe80:(:[0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}){0,4}%[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,}|::(ffff(:0{1,4}){0,1}:){0,1}((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\.){3,3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}:((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\.){3,3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9]))
```

For ease of reading, the following is the above regular expression split at major OR points into separate lines:

```
# IPv6 RegEx
(
([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){7,7}[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|          # 1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8
([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,7}:|                         # 1::                              1:2:3:4:5:6:7::
([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,6}:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|         # 1::8             1:2:3:4:5:6::8  1:2:3:4:5:6::8
([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,5}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,2}|  # 1::7:8           1:2:3:4:5::7:8  1:2:3:4:5::8
([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,3}|  # 1::6:7:8         1:2:3:4::6:7:8  1:2:3:4::8
([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,3}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,4}|  # 1::5:6:7:8       1:2:3::5:6:7:8  1:2:3::8
([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,2}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,5}|  # 1::4:5:6:7:8     1:2::4:5:6:7:8  1:2::8
[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:((:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,6})|       # 1::3:4:5:6:7:8   1::3:4:5:6:7:8  1::8  
:((:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,7}|:)|                     # ::2:3:4:5:6:7:8  ::2:3:4:5:6:7:8 ::8       ::     
fe80:(:[0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}){0,4}%[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,}|     # fe80::7:8%eth0   fe80::7:8%1     (link-local IPv6 addresses with zone index)
::(ffff(:0{1,4}){0,1}:){0,1}
((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\.){3,3}
(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])|          # ::255.255.255.255   ::ffff:255.255.255.255  ::ffff:0:255.255.255.255  (IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses and IPv4-translated addresses)
([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}:
((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\.){3,3}
(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])           # 2001:db8:3:4::192.0.2.33  64:ff9b::192.0.2.33 (IPv4-Embedded IPv6 Address)
)

# IPv4 RegEx
((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\.){3,3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])
```

To make the above easier to understand, the following "pseudo" code replicates the above:

```
IPV4SEG  = (25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])
IPV4ADDR = (IPV4SEG\.){3,3}IPV4SEG
IPV6SEG  = [0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}
IPV6ADDR = (
           (IPV6SEG:){7,7}IPV6SEG|                # 1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8
           (IPV6SEG:){1,7}:|                      # 1::                                 1:2:3:4:5:6:7::
           (IPV6SEG:){1,6}:IPV6SEG|               # 1::8               1:2:3:4:5:6::8   1:2:3:4:5:6::8
           (IPV6SEG:){1,5}(:IPV6SEG){1,2}|        # 1::7:8             1:2:3:4:5::7:8   1:2:3:4:5::8
           (IPV6SEG:){1,4}(:IPV6SEG){1,3}|        # 1::6:7:8           1:2:3:4::6:7:8   1:2:3:4::8
           (IPV6SEG:){1,3}(:IPV6SEG){1,4}|        # 1::5:6:7:8         1:2:3::5:6:7:8   1:2:3::8
           (IPV6SEG:){1,2}(:IPV6SEG){1,5}|        # 1::4:5:6:7:8       1:2::4:5:6:7:8   1:2::8
           IPV6SEG:((:IPV6SEG){1,6})|             # 1::3:4:5:6:7:8     1::3:4:5:6:7:8   1::8
           :((:IPV6SEG){1,7}|:)|                  # ::2:3:4:5:6:7:8    ::2:3:4:5:6:7:8  ::8       ::       
           fe80:(:IPV6SEG){0,4}%[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,}|  # fe80::7:8%eth0     fe80::7:8%1  (link-local IPv6 addresses with zone index)
           ::(ffff(:0{1,4}){0,1}:){0,1}IPV4ADDR|  # ::255.255.255.255  ::ffff:255.255.255.255  ::ffff:0:255.255.255.255 (IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses and IPv4-translated addresses)
           (IPV6SEG:){1,4}:IPV4ADDR               # 2001:db8:3:4::192.0.2.33  64:ff9b::192.0.2.33 (IPv4-Embedded IPv6 Address)
           )
```

I posted a script on GitHub which tests the regular expression: https://gist.github.com/syzdek/6086792

Comment: Excellent response. I only could wish that RegexPlanet worked right now (somehow it won't let me make share link), since I've made non capturing variant and I have added all your examples as test.

Comment: Why are you using escaping in front of `.` in ip4 pattern, while `.` is unescaped in ip6 pattern? Is this intentional?

Comment: You IPv4 regex does not match IPs like `127.000.000.001`

Comment: IPv4 segments should not include leading zeros. If a leading zero is present, the IPv4 segment should be interpreted in octal. So the IPV4SEG above is correct in not allowing '000'. It does however permit '00' which it should not.

Comment: Did not work for me in the browser as I would expect. Validated even reg.test('3zzzzffe:1900:4545:3:200:f8ff:fe21:67cf') which obviously is not a valid IPv6 adress. Had much better results with regex here: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/rasbt/python_reference/blob/master/tutorials/useful_regex.ipynb

Comment: Matches "::_" which is not a valid IP address, as far as I can tell.

Comment: fantastic ipv6 regex. found a small bug with the link local section. you had `fe80` where it should be something like `[fF][eE]80` and a `ffff` which should be something like `[fF]{4}`

Comment: You have mistake in mapped ipv4 it should expect double colon like(([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}:)([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:)IPv4regex

Comment: For IPv4 matching with leading zeros you can use:  (25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)){3}

Comment: Question by Aria http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32368008/regular-expression-that-matches-all-valid-format-ipv6-addresses/32368136 contains answer to last comment.

Comment: +1 for showing that regexes can be (in the same manner as any source code) actually readable if you take the care and format them.

Comment: While writing regex patterns isn't a big deal if you know what you're looking for, it is a mundane and error-prone task. Thanks a lot for taking the time to do this the right way and for also breaking it down with useful comments!

Comment: It doesn't work for me: $ [[ "2001:bobbydavro::1" =~ $RE_IPV6 ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no" yes

Comment: I've put this into Python RE form: https://gist.github.com/dfee/6ed3a4b05cfe7a6faf40a2102408d5d8

Comment: Failing test case: fe80::0202:B3FF:FE1E:8329

Comment: Because some platforms have a lazy exit you get an unintended lazy match, leaving out the last segment of the address. To handle this, you have to move the `(IPV6SEG:){7,7}:` to come after the other compression matches and reverse the order of the compression matches.  (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14453696/4151626)

Comment: ... (continued) ... move the `fe80` rule first and the `:((:IPV6SEG){1,7}` rule last, preceded by the `::(ffff` rule (second to last). `(IPV6SEG:){7,7}:` is third from last.

Comment: ... (continued)... move the `(IPV6SEG:){1,4}:IPV4ADDR` rule ahead of the `(IPV6SEG:){1,4}(:IPVSEG){1,3}` rule.

Comment: Lastly, ... on my platform, for unknown reasons, I had to change the `IPV4SEG` to `(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1{0,1}[0-9]{0,1}[0-9])` or the more rigorous `(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]{0,1}[0-9])` to avoid `09` and `08` being interpreted as illegal octals.

Comment: I have found by chance a form that passes mistakenly: "2. 81fa:a3c:206e:334e:b77f::"

Comment: @ergohack, can you post your working Regex solution to handle the lazy exit?

Comment: @OwN, unfortunately, 78 characters too long and cannot be posted as an alternative answer to this closed thread, ...  I will post it in successive comments, please stitch together carefully: `(fe80:(:[0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}){0,4}%[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,2}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,5}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,3}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,4}|[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:((:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,6})|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,3}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,5}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,2}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,6}:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,7}:`

Comment: @OwN - part 2: `|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){7,7}[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}:((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1{0,1}[0-9]{0,1}[0-9])\.{3,3})(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1{0,1}[0-9]{0,1}[0-9])|::(ffff(:0{1,4}){0,1}:){0,1}((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1{0,1}[0-9]{0,1}[0-9])\.{3,3})(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1{0,1}[0-9]{0,1}[0-9])|:((:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,7}|:))`

Comment: The above regex says this `1::2::3` IPv6 address is valid :)

Comment: All IP address in the middle column are wrong. As per [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/444554/what-does-mean-as-an-ip-address-bracket-colon-colon-bracket), the double colon can be used to replace consecutive blocks of zeroes, IF the length of zeroes is greater than a single block.

Comment: @ChandraNakka no it doesn't.

Comment: fails of f102::1

Comment: Please consider that `[0-9a-fA-F]` wrongly matches with some locales like the Turkish `ç`. You have to use the dedicated characters class names `[[:xdigit:]]` and `[[:digit:]]` or switches the locale to `POSIX` or `C` before performing such Regex match.

Comment: Curious. It [doesn't appear to match](https://regex101.com/r/nveIA8/1) `127.0.0.1` despite the IPv4 segment's presence

Comment: The IPv4 regex can be replaced by 

`((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1?[0-9])?[0-9])\.){3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1?[0-9])?[0-9])`

Comment: I [tested this answer](https://regex101.com/r/dq03km/1) but it didn't work for all ip v6 formats

Comment: Note, since RFC5952, the characters "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", and "f" in an IPv6 address MUST be represented in lowercase.

Answer (score 58):

The following will validate IPv4, IPv6 (full and compressed), and IPv6v4 (full and compressed) addresses:

```
'/^(?>(?>([a-f0-9]{1,4})(?>:(?1)){7}|(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9](?>:|$)){8,})((?1)(?>:(?1)){0,6})?::(?2)?)|(?>(?>(?1)(?>:(?1)){5}:|(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9]:){6,})(?3)?::(?>((?1)(?>:(?1)){0,4}):)?)?(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])(?>\.(?4)){3}))$/iD'
```

Comment: Even though validating ip-s could be done as Frank Krueger suggests, this solution is the one that actually answers the question (though I haven't fully tested it yet) as well as if you have many IP-s that you want syntactically test and maybe match for in a line of text, you can't use the IP validation technique.

Comment: Hi, I tested this RegExp and don't worked for me. It says D is an invalid flag and when I remove it it says "SyntaxError: invalid quantifier"

Comment: What software are you using? This works with PCRE, but not with Perl.

Comment: Front-end javascript. Here is the code I used `var pattern = /PATTERN/;

return [pattern.test(value), 'The Address entered is invalid.'];`

Comment: JavaScript implements a subset of Perl-style regular expressions, not the entirety of PCRE. My regex won't work without some of the advanced features of PCRE.

Comment: This gives exception for me in C#

Comment: Failing test case:
FE80:0000:0000:0000:0202:B3FF:FE1E:8329
Using latest version of Elixir on this date, which uses PCRE underneath.

Comment: C# does not support atomic grouping (e.g. `(?>`).

Comment: This form doesn't work for all possible forms of ipv6

Comment: Check this [demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/fr/regex-tester/1cbae711e6d9) it doesnt' work for 192.168.0.14

Comment: @AmineKOUIS I don't know how that website functions but [this](https://onlinephp.io/c/8e5a1) shows it to work

Answer (score 28):

It sounds like you may be using Python.  If so, you can use something like this:

```
import socket

def check_ipv6(n):
    try:
        socket.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET6, n)
        return True
    except socket.error:
        return False

print check_ipv6('::1') # True
print check_ipv6('foo') # False
print check_ipv6(5)     # TypeError exception
print check_ipv6(None)  # TypeError exception
```

I don't think you have to have IPv6 compiled in to Python to get [`inet_pton`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.inet_pton), which can also parse IPv4 addresses if you pass in `socket.AF_INET` as the first parameter.  Note: this may not work on non-Unix systems.

Comment: You should specify the exception type in the `except` clause. Otherwise, `except` will catch everything and may mask unrelated errors. The type here should be `socket.error`.

Comment: A) inet_pton doesn't throw other exceptions, unless the docs are wrong, and B) even if it did, what else would you return but False?

Comment: Re: other errors... if the user passes in a non-string, TypeError gets eaten.  Clearly a list isn't an ipv6, but I'd probably want to have it carp that I was passing in the wrong type.

Comment: +1 This helped me a lot. A couple of additional points that should be added: 1) socket.inet_pton can be used to test the validity of both families of IP addresses (IP and IPv6). 2) The docs here (http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html) suggest that this is available on Unix platforms. It might not be available on Win-platforms.

Comment: using django and this helps!

Comment: Note: Windows support for inet_pton was added in python 3.4

Answer (score 27):

From "[IPv6 regex](http://vernon.mauery.com/content/projects/linux/ipv6_regex)":

```
(\A([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,1}(:[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,6}\Z)|
(\A([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,2}(:[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,5}\Z)|
(\A([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,3}(:[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,4}\Z)|
(\A([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,4}(:[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,3}\Z)|
(\A([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,5}(:[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,2}\Z)|
(\A([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,6}(:[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,1}\Z)|
(\A(([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,7}|:):\Z)|
(\A:(:[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,7}\Z)|
(\A((([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){6})(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)){3})\Z)|
(\A(([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){5}[0-9a-f]{1,4}:(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)){3})\Z)|
(\A([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){5}:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)){3}\Z)|
(\A([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,1}(:[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,4}:(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)){3}\Z)|
(\A([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,2}(:[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,3}:(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)){3}\Z)|
(\A([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,3}(:[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,2}:(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)){3}\Z)|
(\A([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,4}(:[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,1}:(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)){3}\Z)|
(\A(([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,5}|:):(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)){3}\Z)|
(\A:(:[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,5}:(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)){3}\Z)
```

Comment: Regular expression like this should be a "code smell" that perhaps regular expression are not the best suited solution here. (Although, I guess the op did ask for it...)

Comment: @user712092 -- everyone who has seen a code base with eyesores such as that

Comment: This is a completely unnecessary travesty to REs. The program that generated it didn't understand what it was doing. A human would never do it this way. Don't be fooled by the apparent complexity - REs are indeed "black magic" to many people, but there's no reason to place them on another planet!

Comment: +1 but O.M.G. there has to be a better way to do this :P For reference: for Rails this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965697/rails-3-validate-ipv4-and-ipv6-format

Comment: It is indeed a code smell; however after taking a look you'll see that each regex is fairly concise.  The problem is that there are different patterns created by the 'compression' of ipv6 -- Colons beginning,middle, and end, on top of if you've used your double colon you can't use it again, on top of the total colons before and after the double have to add up.  Perl 6 *might* be able to tackle this, but it is way beyond PCRE syntax. (PS -- I don't count the embedded ipv4 at the end, which is longer than the ipv6 section!)

Answer (score 17):

This catches the loopback(::1) as well and ipv6 addresses.
 changed {} to + and put : inside the first square bracket.

```
([a-f0-9:]+:+)+[a-f0-9]+
```

tested on with ifconfig -a output
http://regexr.com/

Unix or Mac OSx terminal o option returns only the matching output(ipv6) including ::1

```
ifconfig -a | egrep -o '([a-f0-9:]+:+)+[a-f0-9]+'
```

Get All IP addresses (IPv4 OR IPv6) and print match on unix OSx term

```
ifconfig -a | egrep -o '([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}) | (([a-f0-9:]+:+)+[a-f0-9]+)'
```

Comment: I like the simplicity. This eventually worked for me: `ip a | grep -Po '[\w:]+:+[\w:]+'`

Comment: Humor appreciated!

Comment: When i run ipconfig /all, my ip address ends with %10, this expression does not match this part?

Comment: This does not match `2a11::`, which is a valid IPv6 address (and actually a public DNS server).

Answer (score 14):

I'd have to strongly second the answer from [Frank Krueger](/users/338/frank-krueger).

Whilst you say you need a regular expression to match an IPv6 address, I'm assuming what you really need is to be able to check if a given string is a valid IPv6 address. There is a subtle but important distinction here.

There is more than one way to check if a given string is a valid IPv6 address and regular expression matching is only one solution.

Use an existing library if you can. The library will have fewer bugs and its use will result in less code for you to maintain.

The regular expression suggested by [Factor Mystic](/users/1569/factor-mystic) is long and complex. It most likely works, but you should also consider how you'd cope if it unexpectedly fails. The point I'm trying to make here is that if you can't form a required regular expression yourself you won't be able to easily debug it.

If you have no suitable library it may be better to write your own IPv6 validation routine that doesn't depend on regular expressions. If you write it you understand it and if you understand it you can add comments to explain it so that others can also understand and subsequently maintain it.

Act with caution when using a regular expression whose functionality you can't explain to someone else.

Comment: Using two regular expressions, a liberal expression and an exceptions expression to trap invalid addresses allowed by the first, might be easier than one expression (`return ex1.match(S) && ! ex2.match(S)`).

Comment: You're assuming that he is validating individual IPs when he is almost certainly searching for IPs in a large block of text.

Answer (score 10):

This regular expression will match valid IPv6 and IPv4 addresses in accordance with GNU C++ implementation of regex with REGULAR EXTENDED mode used:

```
"^\s*((([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){7}([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){6}(:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}|((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])){3})|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){5}(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,2})|:((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])){3})|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){4}(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,3})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})?:((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])){3}))|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){3}(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,4})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){0,2}:((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])){3}))|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){2}(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,5})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){0,3}:((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])){3}))|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){1}(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,6})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){0,4}:((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])){3}))|:))|(:(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,7})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){0,5}:((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])){3}))|:)))(%.+)?\s*$"
```

Answer (score 7):

I'm not an Ipv6 expert but I think you can get a pretty good result more easily with this one:

```
^([0-9A-Fa-f]{0,4}:){2,7}([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}$|((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\.|$)){4})$
```

to answer "is a valid ipv6" it look like ok to me. To break it down in parts... forget it. I've omitted the unspecified one (::) since  there is no use to have "unpecified adress" in my database.

the beginning:
`^([0-9A-Fa-f]{0,4}:){2,7}` <-- match the compressible part, we can translate this as: between 2 and 7 colon who may have heaxadecimal number between them.

followed by:
`[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}$` <-- an hexadecimal number (leading 0 omitted)
OR
`((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\.|$)){4}` <-- an Ipv4 adress

Comment: +1 for actually sticking to the OPs question and presenting a relatively handsome regex that somewhat works.

Comment: This don't match "::1"

Comment: Huh? In java regex syntaxt it does match:
`start() = 0, end() = 3
group(0) = "::1"
group(1) = ":"
group(2) = "1"
group(3) = "null"
group(4) = "null"
group(5) = "null"`

Comment: Somewhere else someone notify me of a problem with my regex, compressed part "::" can only appear once. So "::1::2" would match with my regex but it's not a valid IPV6. A second regex may validate this case. The full recommendation was to use a stateful parser to validate. I agree that resulting code will be easier to read and maintain (and someone probably already coded it in an open source somewhere).

Comment: IPv4 regex also isn't perfect. For example, `1.1.1.1.` would match with it. I.e. any address with a trailing dot.

Answer (score 5):

If you use Perl try [Net::IPv6Addr](https://metacpan.org/module/Net::IPv6Addr)

```
use Net::IPv6Addr;

if( defined Net::IPv6Addr::is_ipv6($ip_address) ){
  print "Looks like an ipv6 address\n";
}
```

[NetAddr::IP](https://metacpan.org/module/NetAddr::IP)

```
use NetAddr::IP;

my $obj = NetAddr::IP->new6($ip_address);
```

[Validate::IP](https://metacpan.org/module/Data::Validate::IP)

```
use Validate::IP qw'is_ipv6';

if( is_ipv6($ip_address) ){
  print "Looks like an ipv6 address\n";
}
```

Comment: Or Data::Validate::IP http://search.cpan.org/~neely/Data-Validate-IP-0.11/lib/Data/Validate/IP.pm.

Answer (score 5):

Beware! **In Java, the use of InetAddress and related classes (Inet4Address, Inet6Address, URL) may involve network trafic!** E.g. DNS resolving (URL.equals, InetAddress from string!). This call may take long and is blocking!

For IPv6 I have something like this. This of course does not handle the very subtle details of IPv6 like that zone indices are allowed only on some classes of IPv6 addresses. And this regex is not written for group capturing, it is only a "matches" kind of regexp.

`S` - IPv6 segment = `[0-9a-f]{1,4}`

`I` - IPv4 = `(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9]{1,2})\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9]{1,2})`

Schematic (first part matches IPv6 addresses with IPv4 suffix, second part matches IPv6 addresses, last patrt the zone index):

```
(
(
::(S:){0,5}|
S::(S:){0,4}|
(S:){2}:(S:){0,3}|
(S:){3}:(S:){0,2}|
(S:){4}:(S:)?|
(S:){5}:|
(S:){6}
)
I

|

:(:|(:S){1,7})|
S:(:|(:S){1,6})|
(S:){2}(:|(:S){1,5})|
(S:){3}(:|(:S){1,4})|
(S:){4}(:|(:S){1,3})|
(S:){5}(:|(:S){1,2})|
(S:){6}(:|(:S))|
(S:){7}:|
(S:){7}S
)

(?:%[0-9a-z]+)?
```

And here the might regex (case insensitive, surround with what ever needed like beginning/end of line, etc.):

```
(?:
(?:
::(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){0,5}|
[0-9a-f]{1,4}::(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){0,4}|
(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){2}:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){0,3}|
(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){3}:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){0,2}|
(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){4}:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:)?|
(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){5}:|
(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){6}
)
(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9]{1,2})\.){3}
(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9]{1,2})|

:(?::|(?::[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,7})|
[0-9a-f]{1,4}:(?::|(?::[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,6})|
(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){2}(?::|(?::[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,5})|
(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){3}(?::|(?::[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,4})|
(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){4}(?::|(?::[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,3})|
(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){5}(?::|(?::[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,2})|
(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){6}(?::|(?::[0-9a-f]{1,4}))|
(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){7}:|
(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){7}[0-9a-f]{1,4}
)

(?:%[0-9a-z]+)?
```

Comment: Only works if you force it to match from begin to end of line and the line only contains an IPv6 address, otherwise it may only match part of the address; see here https://regex101.com/r/QZJu0x/1

Answer (score 5):

Following regex is for IPv6 only. Group 1 matches with the IP.

```
(([0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}:){1,7}[0-9a-fA-F]{0,4})
```

Comment: +1 It is not always necessary to have a perfect super complex regex that a human can't understand. I will use this one because I understand what it does and in my case, I can be sure that if I got something that resembles a valid ipv6, so it is a valid ipv6.

Comment: this wouldn't match say:
fe80::1
or 
2342:32fd::2d32

Comment: The regex matches: 2020-09-09 **16:36:10**,978 INFO success: nginx entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs).

Comment: @Kaymaz use some context in your regex. Compression can't be easily regexed, as you see on the top replies.

Comment: (([0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}:){7}[0-9a-fA-F]{0,4})
{1,7} it's violating  the ipv6 rules. replace with {7}

Answer (score 4):

A simple regex that will match, but I wouldn't recommend for validation of any sort is this:

```
([A-Fa-f0-9]{1,4}::?){1,7}[A-Fa-f0-9]{1,4}
```

Note this matches compression anywhere in the address, though it won't match the loopback address ::1.  I find this a reasonable compromise in order to keep the regex simple.

I successfully use this in iTerm2 *smart selection rules* to quad-click IPv6 addresses.

Comment: You meant `A-F`, not `A-Z`! Also note that you are excluding dotted-quad notation.

Comment: It would match with something like `1::2::3::4::5::6::7::8`. Sadly, there's no easy way to implement the compressed IPv6 addresses.

Comment: It matches the invalid address`1::2::3`, while cannot match the valid address `2a11::`.

Answer (score 4):

Regexes for ipv6 can get really tricky when you consider addresses with embedded ipv4 and addresses that are compressed, as you can see from some of these answers.

[The open-source IPAddress Java library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/) will validate all standard representations of IPv6 and IPv4 and also supports prefix-length (and validation of such).  Disclaimer: I am the project manager of that library.

Code example:

```
        try {
            IPAddressString str = new IPAddressString("::1");
            IPAddress addr = str.toAddress();
            if(addr.isIPv6() || addr.isIPv6Convertible()) {
                IPv6Address ipv6Addr = addr.toIPv6();
            }
            //use address
        } catch(AddressStringException e) {
            //e.getMessage has validation error
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the patterns included in the other answers there are a number of good patterns that can be improved by referencing groups and utilizing lookaheads.  Here is an example of a pattern that is self referencing that I would utilize in PHP if I had to:

```
^(?<hgroup>(?<hex>[[:xdigit:]]{0,4}) # grab a sequence of up to 4 hex digits
                                     # and name this pattern for usage later
     (?<!:::):{1,2})                 # match 1 or 2 ':' characters
                                     # as long as we can't match 3
 (?&hgroup){1,6} # match our hex group 1 to 6 more times
 (?:(?:
    # match an ipv4 address or
    (?<dgroup>2[0-5]|(?:2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\.){3}(?&dgroup)
    # match our hex group one last time
    |(?&hex))$
```

**Note:** PHP has a built in filter for this which would be a better solution than this 
pattern.

[Regex101 Analysis](http://regex101.com/r/qZ5wF3)

Answer (score 2):

In **Scala** use the well known Apache Commons validators.

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-validator/commons-validator/1.4.1

```
libraryDependencies += "commons-validator" % "commons-validator" % "1.4.1"


import org.apache.commons.validator.routines._

/**
 * Validates if the passed ip is a valid IPv4 or IPv6 address.
 *
 * @param ip The IP address to validate.
 * @return True if the passed IP address is valid, false otherwise.
 */  
 def ip(ip: String) = InetAddressValidator.getInstance().isValid(ip)
```

Following the test's of the method `ip(ip: String)`:

```
"The `ip` validator" should {
  "return false if the IPv4 is invalid" in {
    ip("123") must beFalse
    ip("255.255.255.256") must beFalse
    ip("127.1") must beFalse
    ip("30.168.1.255.1") must beFalse
    ip("-1.2.3.4") must beFalse
  }

  "return true if the IPv4 is valid" in {
    ip("255.255.255.255") must beTrue
    ip("127.0.0.1") must beTrue
    ip("0.0.0.0") must beTrue
  }

  //IPv6
  //@see: http://www.ronnutter.com/ipv6-cheatsheet-on-identifying-valid-ipv6-addresses/
  "return false if the IPv6 is invalid" in {
    ip("1200::AB00:1234::2552:7777:1313") must beFalse
  }

  "return true if the IPv6 is valid" in {
    ip("1200:0000:AB00:1234:0000:2552:7777:1313") must beTrue
    ip("21DA:D3:0:2F3B:2AA:FF:FE28:9C5A") must beTrue
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, It claims to check that it is a valid address, "_Validates if the passed ip is a valid IPv4 or IPv6 address._", but it really only checks that it is formatted as a valid address. For instance, `1200:0000:AB00:1234:0000:2552:7777:1313` is a valid format for an IPv6 address, but it is not a valid IPv6 address as the test method returns. I'll bet it thinks `241.54.113.65` is a valid IPv4 address.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your needs, an approximation like:

```
[0-9a-f:]+
```

may be enough (as with simple log file grepping, for example.)

Answer (score 2):

I generated the following using python and works with the re module. The look-ahead assertions ensure that the correct number of dots or colons appear in the address.  It does not support IPv4 in IPv6 notation.

```
pattern = '^(?=\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$)(?:(?:25[0-5]|[12][0-4][0-9]|1[5-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.?){4}$|(?=^(?:[0-9a-f]{0,4}:){2,7}[0-9a-f]{0,4}$)(?![^:]*::.+::[^:]*$)(?:(?=.*::.*)|(?=\w+:\w+:\w+:\w+:\w+:\w+:\w+:\w+))(?:(?:^|:)(?:[0-9a-f]{4}|[1-9a-f][0-9a-f]{0,3})){0,8}(?:::(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}(?:$|:)){0,6})?$'
result = re.match(pattern, ip)
if result: result.group(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you can use the library class `sun.net.util.IPAddressUtil`:

```
IPAddressUtil.isIPv6LiteralAddress(iPaddress);
```

Comment: sun.net.* is private API.

Answer (score 1):

Using Ruby? Try this:

```
/^(((?=.*(::))(?!.*\3.+\3))\3?|[\dA-F]{1,4}:)([\dA-F]{1,4}(\3|:\b)|\2){5}(([\dA-F]{1,4}(\3|:\b|$)|\2){2}|(((2[0-4]|1\d|[1-9])?\d|25[0-5])\.?\b){4})\z/i
```

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to find a regular expression which works for all IPv6 cases. They are usually hard to maintain, not easily readable and may cause performance problems. Hence, I want to share an alternative solution which I have developed: [Regular Expression (RegEx) for IPv6 Separate from IPv4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631669/regular-expression-regex-for-ipv6-separate-from-ipv4/28289229#28289229)

Now you may ask that "This method only finds IPv6, how can I find IPv6 in a text or file?" Here are methods for this issue too.

**Note**: If you do not want to use IPAddress class in .NET, you can also replace it with [my method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631669/regular-expression-regex-for-ipv6-separate-from-ipv4/28289229#28289229). It also covers mapped IPv4 and special cases too, while IPAddress does not cover.

```
class IPv6
{
    public List<string> FindIPv6InFile(string filePath)
    {
        Char ch;
        StringBuilder sbIPv6 = new StringBuilder();
        List<string> listIPv6 = new List<string>();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath);
        do
        {
            bool hasColon = false;
            int length = 0;

            do
            {
                ch = (char)reader.Read();

                if (IsEscapeChar(ch))
                    break;

                //Check the first 5 chars, if it has colon, then continue appending to stringbuilder
                if (!hasColon && length < 5)
                {
                    if (ch == ':')
                    {
                        hasColon = true;
                    }
                    sbIPv6.Append(ch.ToString());
                }
                else if (hasColon) //if no colon in first 5 chars, then dont append to stringbuilder
                {
                    sbIPv6.Append(ch.ToString());
                }

                length++;

            } while (!reader.EndOfStream);

            if (hasColon && !listIPv6.Contains(sbIPv6.ToString()) && IsIPv6(sbIPv6.ToString()))
            {
                listIPv6.Add(sbIPv6.ToString());
            }

            sbIPv6.Clear();

        } while (!reader.EndOfStream);
        reader.Close();
        reader.Dispose();

        return listIPv6;
    }

    public List<string> FindIPv6InText(string text)
    {
        StringBuilder sbIPv6 = new StringBuilder();
        List<string> listIPv6 = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
        {
            bool hasColon = false;
            int length = 0;

            do
            {
                if (IsEscapeChar(text[length + i]))
                    break;

                //Check the first 5 chars, if it has colon, then continue appending to stringbuilder
                if (!hasColon && length < 5)
                {
                    if (text[length + i] == ':')
                    {
                        hasColon = true;
                    }
                    sbIPv6.Append(text[length + i].ToString());
                }
                else if (hasColon) //if no colon in first 5 chars, then dont append to stringbuilder
                {
                    sbIPv6.Append(text[length + i].ToString());
                }

                length++;

            } while (i + length != text.Length);

            if (hasColon && !listIPv6.Contains(sbIPv6.ToString()) && IsIPv6(sbIPv6.ToString()))
            {
                listIPv6.Add(sbIPv6.ToString());
            }

            i += length;
            sbIPv6.Clear();
        }

        return listIPv6;
    }

    bool IsEscapeChar(char ch)
    {
        if (ch != ' ' && ch != '\r' && ch != '\n' && ch!='\t')
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    bool IsIPv6(string maybeIPv6)
    {
        IPAddress ip;
        if (IPAddress.TryParse(maybeIPv6, out ip))
        {
            return ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`InetAddressUtils` has all the patterns defined. I ended-up using their pattern directly, and am pasting it here for reference:

```
private static final String IPV4_BASIC_PATTERN_STRING =
        "(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\\.){3}" + // initial 3 fields, 0-255 followed by .
         "([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])"; // final field, 0-255

private static final Pattern IPV4_PATTERN =
    Pattern.compile("^" + IPV4_BASIC_PATTERN_STRING + "$");

private static final Pattern IPV4_MAPPED_IPV6_PATTERN = // TODO does not allow for redundant leading zeros
        Pattern.compile("^::[fF]{4}:" + IPV4_BASIC_PATTERN_STRING + "$");

private static final Pattern IPV6_STD_PATTERN =
    Pattern.compile(
            "^[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){7}$");

private static final Pattern IPV6_HEX_COMPRESSED_PATTERN =
    Pattern.compile(
            "^(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}(:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){0,5})?)" + // 0-6 hex fields
             "::" +
             "(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}(:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){0,5})?)$"); // 0-6 hex fields
```

Comment: The last regex allows 6 hex fields plus '::' plus 6 other hex fields, which would make it a tad too long IPv6 address...

Answer (score 0):

For PHP 5.2+ users `filter_var` works great.

I know this doesn't answer the original question (specifically a regex solution), but I post this in the hope it may help someone else in the future.

```
$is_ip4address = (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV4) !== FALSE);
$is_ip6address = (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV6) !== FALSE);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for IPv4 and IPv6:

```
^(([0-9a-f]{0,4}:){1,7}[0-9a-f]{1,4}|([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})$
```

Comment: It matches invalid addresses with 2 instances of `::`. e.g. `2404:6800::4003:c02::8a`

Comment: matches invalid IPv4 666.666.666.666

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with, using a bit of lookahead and named groups.  This is of course just IPv6, but it shouldn't interfere with additional patterns if you want to add IPv4:

```
(?=([0-9a-f]+(:[0-9a-f])*)?(?P<wild>::)(?!([0-9a-f]+:)*:))(::)?([0-9a-f]{1,4}:{1,2}){0,6}(?(wild)[0-9a-f]{0,4}|[0-9a-f]{1,4}:[0-9a-f]{1,4})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just matching local ones from an origin with square brackets included. I know it's not as comprehensive but in javascript the other ones had difficult to trace issues primarily that of not working, so this seems to get me what I needed for now. extra capitals A-F aren't needed either.

```
^\[([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4})(\:{1,2})([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4})(\:{1,2})([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4})(\:{1,2})([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4})(\:{1,2})([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4})\]
```

Jinnko's version is simplified and better I see.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, another way to get an IPv6 textual representation **validating** parser is to use programming. Here is one that is fully compliant with RFC-4291 and RFC-5952. I've written this code in ANSI C (works with GCC, passed tests on Linux - works with clang, passed tests on FreeBSD). Thus, it does only rely on the ANSI C standard library, so it can be compiled everywhere (I've used it for IPv6 parsing inside a kernel module with FreeBSD).

```
// IPv6 textual representation validating parser fully compliant with RFC-4291 and RFC-5952
// BSD-licensed / Copyright 2015-2017 Alexandre Fenyo

#include <string.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef enum { false, true } bool;

static const char hexdigits[] = "0123456789abcdef";
static int digit2int(const char digit) {
  return strchr(hexdigits, digit) - hexdigits;
}

// This IPv6 address parser handles any valid textual representation according to RFC-4291 and RFC-5952.
// Other representations will return -1.
//
// note that str input parameter has been modified when the function call returns
//
// parse_ipv6(char *str, struct in6_addr *retaddr)
// parse textual representation of IPv6 addresses
// str:     input arg
// retaddr: output arg
int parse_ipv6(char *str, struct in6_addr *retaddr) {
  bool compressed_field_found = false;
  unsigned char *_retaddr = (unsigned char *) retaddr;
  char *_str = str;
  char *delim;

  bzero((void *) retaddr, sizeof(struct in6_addr));
  if (!strlen(str) || strchr(str, ':') == NULL || (str[0] == ':' && str[1] != ':') ||
      (strlen(str) >= 2 && str[strlen(str) - 1] == ':' && str[strlen(str) - 2] != ':')) return -1;

  // convert transitional to standard textual representation
  if (strchr(str, '.')) {
    int ipv4bytes[4];
    char *curp = strrchr(str, ':');
    if (curp == NULL) return -1;
    char *_curp = ++curp;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      char *nextsep = strchr(_curp, '.');
      if (_curp[0] == '0' || (i < 3 && nextsep == NULL) || (i == 3 && nextsep != NULL)) return -1;
      if (nextsep != NULL) *nextsep = 0;
      int j;
      for (j = 0; j < strlen(_curp); j++) if (_curp[j] < '0' || _curp[j] > '9') return -1;
      if (strlen(_curp) > 3) return -1;
      const long val = strtol(_curp, NULL, 10);
      if (val < 0 || val > 255) return -1;
      ipv4bytes[i] = val;
      _curp = nextsep + 1;
    }
    sprintf(curp, "%x%02x:%x%02x", ipv4bytes[0], ipv4bytes[1], ipv4bytes[2], ipv4bytes[3]);
  }

  // parse standard textual representation
  do {
    if ((delim = strchr(_str, ':')) == _str || (delim == NULL && !strlen(_str))) {
      if (delim == str) _str++;
      else if (delim == NULL) return 0;
      else {
        if (compressed_field_found == true) return -1;
        if (delim == str + strlen(str) - 1 && _retaddr != (unsigned char *) (retaddr + 1)) return 0;
        compressed_field_found = true;
        _str++;
        int cnt = 0;
        char *__str;
        for (__str = _str; *__str; ) if (*(__str++) == ':') cnt++;
        unsigned char *__retaddr = - 2 * ++cnt + (unsigned char *) (retaddr + 1);
        if (__retaddr <= _retaddr) return -1;
        _retaddr = __retaddr;
      }
    } else {
      char hexnum[4] = "0000";
      if (delim == NULL) delim = str + strlen(str);
      if (delim - _str > 4) return -1;
      int i;
      for (i = 0; i < delim - _str; i++)
        if (!isxdigit(_str[i])) return -1;
        else hexnum[4 - (delim - _str) + i] = tolower(_str[i]);
      _str = delim + 1;
      *(_retaddr++) = (digit2int(hexnum[0]) << 4) + digit2int(hexnum[1]);
      *(_retaddr++) = (digit2int(hexnum[2]) << 4) + digit2int(hexnum[3]);
    }
  } while (_str < str + strlen(str));
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The regex allows the use of leading zeros in the IPv4 parts.

Some Unix and Mac distros convert those segments into octals.

I suggest using `25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d` as an IPv4 segment.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [the ipextract shell tools](https://github.com/philpraxis/ipextract) I made for this purpose. They are based on regexp and grep.

Usage:

```
$ ifconfig | ipextract6
fe80::1%lo0
::1
fe80::7ed1:c3ff:feec:dee1%en0
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this small one-liner. It should only match valid uncompressed/compressed IPv6 addresses (no IPv4 hybrids)

```
/(?!.*::.*::)(?!.*:::.*)(?!:[a-f0-9])((([a-f0-9]{1,4})?[:](?!:)){7}|(?=(.*:[:a-f0-9]{1,4}::|^([:a-f0-9]{1,4})?::))(([a-f0-9]{1,4})?[:]{1,2}){1,6})[a-f0-9]{1,4}/
```

Comment: Actually, valid IPv6 addresses include uncompressed, compressed, uncompressed-hybrid, and compressed hybrid. It really takes a lot more than what you have to actually match any valid text representation of an IPv6 address.

Answer (score -2):

If you want only normal IP-s (no slashes), here:

```
^(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}(?:::)?){0,7}::[0-9a-f]+$
```

I use it for my syntax highlighter in hosts file editor application. Works as charm.

Comment: No way that this ever works decently, it can't match a single ipv6 address with a single colon in it, all your matches are on double colons, and you explicitly require a double colon for your last group, summarization can happen anywhere... .

Comment: (?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}(?:::?)?){0,7}::?[0-9a-f]{1,4}

Comment: Still wrong, but even then you'll end up repeating JinnKo's answer, which is good enough for simple purposes, but still has flaws (does not catch double summarization and doesn't allow dotted quads, nor localhost, nor :: termination, ...)