# xn-- on domain, what it means?

Tags: dns

I want to know what the xn-- (domain) -66b.com means in a domain. For example, I bought diseñolatinoamericano.com with ñ.

And in mozilla it appears http://xn--diseolatinoamericano-66b.com/ also in Facebook I can't link anything.

Thanks!

Comment: Google search "ACE prefix"

Comment: That wasn't very helpful. I get very irrelevant results.

Comment: If you like more information about xn-- have a look at [Is there any way to avoid showing "xn--" for IDN domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11008602/is-there-any-way-to-avoid-showing-xn-for-idn-domains)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Its the result of IDNA encoding; i.e. [converting your unicode domain name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name) to its ASCII equivalent which has to be done as DNS is not unicode-aware.

The `xn--` says "everything that follows is encoded-unicode".

Comment: FYI, xn stands for _eXtended Names_.

Comment: @noddy That is absolutely NOT true. The `xn--` prefix was chosen **randomly** when the standard finalized. See http://www.ccwhois.org/mailarchive/cctld-discuss/vol05/0096.html   Of course you are free to artificially add any semantic on it you want, but this is certainly not how it was created.

Comment: Note: ccwhois.org is down for me, but perhaps another suitable citation might be https://web.archive.org/web/20180530223920/http://www.atm.tut.fi/list-archive/ietf-announce/msg13572.html

Answer (score 32):

This is [Punycode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode) which is used to [Internationalize Domain Names in Applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name#Internationalizing_Domain_Names_in_Applications).

From [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode):

> Punycode is intended for the encoding of labels in the
>   Internationalized Domain Names in Applications (IDNA) framework, such
>   that these domain names may be represented in the ASCII character set
>   allowed in the Domain Name System of the Internet. The encoding syntax
>   is defined in IETF document RFC 3492.

From [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name#Internationalizing_Domain_Names_in_Applications):

> Internationalizing Domain Names in Applications (IDNA) is a mechanism
>   defined in 2003 for handling internationalized domain names containing
>   non-ASCII characters. These names either are Latin letters with
>   diacritics (ñ, é) or are written in languages or scripts which do not
>   use the Latin alphabet: Arabic, Hangul, Hiragana and Kanji for
>   instance. Although the Domain Name System supports non-ASCII
>   characters, applications such as e-mail and web browsers restrict the
>   characters which can be used as domain names for purposes such as a
>   hostname.

Answer (score 9):

The (simplified) semantic of `66b` (i.e. the string after the last `-`) in your example is: "Move the cursor in `diseolatinoamericano` 4 chars to the right and insert a `ñ`". The one bigger code `76b` (in little endian) means to move one more char and so:

```
$ idn2 -d xn--diseolatinoamericano-76b
diseoñlatinoamericano
```

. If you further increase the code you get:

```
-76b -> diseoñlatinoamericano
-86b -> diseolñatinoamericano
-96b -> diseolañtinoamericano
-b7b -> diseolatñinoamericano
-c7b -> diseolatiñnoamericano
-d7b -> diseolatinñoamericano
-e7b -> diseolatinoñamericano
-f7b -> diseolatinoañmericano
...
-m7b -> diseolatinoamericanño
-n7b -> diseolatinoamericanoñ
```

resulting in the position of the `ñ` moving further to the right.

After this increasing the code once more resets the insertion position to the start of the string and increases the codepoint of the character to insert by one. `ñ` has the codepoint 241, the next is `ò` and so:

```
-o7b -> òdiseolatinoamericano
-p7b -> dòiseolatinoamericano
...
```

The exact details (e.g. why `-a6b` had to be skipped above) can be found in [rfc3492](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3492).

Comment: Well you've piqued my curiosity, but without a very deep reading of the RFC I can't find out why `-a6b` is skipped.  Any clues?  Thanks.

Comment: @mwfearnley The reason is in https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3492#section-3.3, that is, `-a6b` encodes two numbers and so `xn--diseolatinoamericano-6ab` has two codepoints inserted. (check `idn2 -d xn--diseolatinoamericano-6ab | hexdump -C`)

Comment: @mwfearnley Notice, that the letters precede the numbers in the encoding, so `a` is the smallest possible digit, which in this case falls under the first threshold, and thus would terminate the variable length number if present as the first digit. (@Uwe Kleine-König, please correct me if I'm wrong!)