# Is there any way to avoid showing "xn--" for IDN domains?

Tags: url, unicode, dns, idn, punycode

If I use a domain such as *www.äöü.com*, is there any way to avoid it being displayed as *www.xn--4ca0bs.com* in users’ browsers?

Domains such as *www.xn--4ca0bs.com* cause a lot of confusion with average internet users, I guess.

Comment: Not using IDNs at all would be a solution. ;)

Comment: The answers here are obsolete as of 2023; browsers generally display names in the human-readable way now, provided the the name is readable *in any single culture.* Browsers now disregard homographs when deciding how to display domain names (but FYI, registries have rules regarding registering homograph domains).

Answer (score 10):

This is entirely up to the browser. In fact, IDNs are pretty much a browser-only technology. Domain names cannot contain non-ASCII characters, so the actual domain name is always the Punycode encoded `xn--...` form. It's up to the browser to prettify this, but many choose to not do so to avoid domain name spoofing using lookalike Unicode characters.

Comment: Domain names can contain non-ASCII characters. Russia, China and Serbia already allow users to register such domains. See http://www.w3.org/International/articles/idn-and-iri/

Comment: But the *actual* domain name in the DNS system cannot. That's why they're encoded into the `xn--...` Punycode format.

Comment: Hence the name IDNA: International Domain Names **in Applications**.

Comment: This is really interesting. I'm just learning about this now. [Here is](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/idn.md) chrome's policy for deciding whether to prettify internationalized domain names.

Answer (score 6):

From a security perspective, Unicode domains can be problematic because many Unicode characters are difficult to distinguish from common ASCII characters (or indeed other Unicode characters).

It is possible to register domains such as "xn–pple-43d.com", which is equivalent to "аpple.com". It may not be obvious at first glance, but "аpple.com" uses the Cyrillic "а" (U+0430) rather than the ASCII "a" (U+0061). This is known as a [homograph attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDN_homograph_attack).

Fortunately modern browsers have mechanisms in place to limit IDN homograph attacks. The page [IDN Policy on chrome](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/idn.md) highlights the conditions under which an IDN is displayed in its native Unicode form. Generally speaking, the Unicode form will be hidden if a domain label contains characters from multiple different languages. The "аpple.com" domain as described above will appear in its Punycode form as "xn–pple-43d.com" to limit confusion with the real "apple.com".

For more information see [this blog post by Xudong Zheng](https://www.xudongz.com/blog/2017/idn-phishing/).

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer 8.0 on Windows 7 displays your UTF-8 domain just fine.
Google Chrome 19 on the other hand doesn't.

Read more here: [An Introduction to Multilingual Web Addresses #phishing](http://www.w3.org/International/articles/idn-and-iri/#phishing).

Different browsers to things differently, possibly because some use the system codepage/locale/encoding/wtvr. And others use their own settings, or a list of allowed characters.

Read that article carefully, it explains how each browser works when making a decision.
If you are targeting a specific language, you can get away with it and make it work.