# Punycode is showing instead of Unicode in URL

Tags: url, unicode, non-ascii-characters, idn, punycode

The domain in question is **amammerɛ.net**. Punycode: xn--amammer-1dd.net. But when I load the site xn--amammer-1dd.net is showing instead of amammerɛ.net? Why is this please? I'm new when it comes to IDN's but I would like to have special characters in my domain. Please can anyone help me because there are some web addresses that show the special characters but mine is not showing them?

For example this site: [https://www.tubarão.com/](https://www.xn--tubaro-7ta.com/) is showing the special characters and not the punycode.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode#Internationalized_domain_names

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to avoid showing "xn--" for IDN domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11008602/is-there-any-way-to-avoid-showing-xn-for-idn-domains) (in particular [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49667560/157957)).

Comment: Yes it does, thank you @IMSoP!