# Google chrome doesn't open flowər.com

Tags: dns

I have a domain name registered 'flowər.com' where the letter 'e' is inversed. This domain opens in safari, but not in google chrome. When I open it in chrome, it changes it to 'xn--flowr-hlc.com/'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [xn-- on domain, what it means?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9724379/xn-on-domain-what-it-means)

Comment: "When I open it in chrome, it changes it to 'xn--flowr-hlc.com/'." This is by design, and a security measure, because you are mixing characters from different scripts in a way often abused for phishing or equivalent. But your question is offtopic here. Also Chrome opens the site but just shows the URL differently. In fact it tells you exactly that: "Fake site ahead
Attackers sometimes mimic sites by making small, hard-to-see changes to the URL."

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but not all browsers have support for domains with non-ASCII characters. This isn't an issue with your DNS, 'xn--flowr-hlc.com' is the ASCII equivalent of 'flowər.com'. While it will not help, you can always flush your DNS cache on Windows by running `ifconfig /flushdns` in the command prompt.

The good news is that Firefox does support them.

[image]

Comment: Don't say "special" because no character is special, nor "emoji domains" because that is not the official name, they are called IDN for Internationalized Domain Name and very few cases exist with emoji, only in a few ccTLDs like .ws or .tk, as otherwise the main technical specification called IDNA prohibits using emojis in domain names (for obvious technical and non technical reasons) which is what all gTLDs have to follow.