# How connect spring docker container to neo4j

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-neo4j

I tried to dockerize my spring neo4j application.

It works locally when I use `spring.neo4j.uri=bolt://localhost:7687` but, when I'm trying to put it in container and give it address `bolt://registration_db:7687` (registration_db is name of container where neo4j is running) as environment variable i get exception:

Neo4jRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableNeo4jRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'neo4jTemplate' while setting bean property 'neo4jOperations'

....

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'neo4jClient' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/neo4j/Neo4jDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'neo4jClient' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'neo4jDriver' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/neo4j/Neo4jAutoConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.neo4j.driver.Driver]: Factory method 'neo4jDriver' threw exception with message: Invalid address format `bolt://registration_db:7687/neo4j`

pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
    <version>7.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Currently i didn't change default spring boot neo4j configuration, should I try to configure it somehow or there is a other way to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out, that '_' symbol is forbidden in address in spring neo4j, so easy fix was to change container name  with database from registration_db to registration-db. So bolt://registration-db:7687 is valid as address (somehow).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133424/what-are-the-valid-characters-that-can-show-up-in-a-url-host.