# Pcrepp - Perl Regular Expression syntax to match host name

Tags: c++, regex, perl, parsing, pcre

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The Hostname Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418423/the-hostname-regex)

I'm trying to use pcrepp (PCRE) to extract hostname from url.
the pcre regular expression is as same as Perl 5 regular expression.

for example:

```
url = "http://www.pandora.com/#/volume/73";
// the match will be "http://www.pandora.com/".
```

I can't find the correct syntax of the regex for this example.

- Needs to work for any url: `amazon.com/sds/` should return: `amazon.com`. 
  or `abebooks.co.uk/isbn="62345627457245"/blabla/` should return `abebooks.co.uk`
- I don't need to check if the url is valid. just to get the hostname.

Comment: A similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418423/the-hostname-regex

Comment: Are you trying to check if a URL is valid, or just trying to extract the hostname from a valid URL?

Comment: trying to extract the hostname from a valid URL.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
^(?:[a-z]+://)?[^/]+/?
```

Comment: what if I have "amazon.com/abc" ? I can't use only slash for that kind of address.

Comment: If there is no protocol, look for the first slash. With the regular expression this is `^([a-z]+://)?[^/]+/`. You probably should mention this detail in your question rather than hiding it in a comment to an answer. It's a very important detail.

Answer (score 2):

See [Regexp::Common::URI::http](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Regexp::Common::URI::http) which uses sub-patterns defined in [Regexp::Common::URI::RFC2396](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Regexp::Common::URI::RFC2396). Examining the source code of those modules should give you a good idea how to put together a decent pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possibility:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.(com|org|net|mil|edu|COM|ORG|NET|MIL|EDU)$
```

And another:

```
^http\://[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(/\S*)?$
```

These and other URL related regular expressions can be found here: [Regular Expression Library](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=url)

Answer (score 1):

```
string regex1, regex2, finalRegex; 
regex1 = "^((\\w+):\\/\\/\\/?)?((\\w+):?(\\w+)?@)?([^\\/\\?:]+):?(\\d+)?(\\/?[^\\?#;\\|]+)?([;\\|])?([^\\?#]+)?\\??";

regex2 = "([^#]+)?#?(\\w*)";

    //concatenation
    finalRegex= regex1+regex2;
```

the result will be at the sixth place.
answered in another question I asked: [Details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360063/pcrecpp-pcre-extract-hostname-from-url-code-problem).