# hostname regex help

Tags: regex

I have this hostname regex that I'd like to expand on a bit. It will match hostnames such as:

yahoo.com

mail.yahoo.com

but will also match

&^%yahoo.com
etc...

```
(\w+\.\w+\.\w+)
```

Can someone tell me what I need to add to only allow letters, numbers and periods?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The Hostname Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418423/the-hostname-regex)

Comment: `[a-zA-Z0-9]` or `[\d\w]` will match those.  So, something like `[\d\w.]+\.[\d\w]+\.?[\d\w]*`

Comment: @Ethan `\d` is included in `\w`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using 
`[a-zA-Z0-9\.]+` instead of `\w+`.

So all in all this will be:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9\.]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9\.]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9\.]+)
```

Comment: Thanks Dennis, that works. I'll credit you when the wait period ends.

Comment: @jim, why do you want to match something like "............." ? Maybe you want to use a online test tool like this here: [http://www.rubular.com/r/4AQ9ASZJpc](http://www.rubular.com/r/4AQ9ASZJpc)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you tried Google. [Regular expression to match DNS hostname or IP Address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-hostname-or-ip-address)

Answer (score 0):

`\w` should not match `&^%`. I think you are missing anchors.

Try `\b`, that matches a word boundary.

```
\b\w+\.\w+\.\w+\b
```

But hopefully you are aware that this regex is very simplified? There has been already some question and answers to that topic, e.g. [1141848/regex-to-match-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141848/regex-to-match-url)

Comment: Thanks stema. I didn't have the anchors as you suggested. I'll give this a try now