# Regex to find hostname from Jdbc url

Tags: java, regex

I am new to regex. I would like to retrieve the Hostname from postgreSQL jdbc URL using regex.

Assume the postgreSQL url will be `jdbc:postgresql://production:5432/dbname`. I need to retrieve "production", which is the hostname. I want to try with regex and not with Java split function. I tried with

```
Pattern PortFinderPattern = Pattern.compile("[//](.*):*");
final Matcher match = PortFinderPattern.matcher(url);
if (match.find()) {
    System.out.println(match.group(1));
}
```

But it's matching all the string from hostname till the end.

Answer (score 1):

```
Pattern PortFinderPattern = Pattern.compile(".*:\/\/([^:]+).*");
```

Answer (score 1):

regex without grouping :

```
"(?<=//)[^:]*"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[//]([\\w\\d\\-\\.]+)\:
```

Should be enough to find it reliably. Though this is probably a better regex:

[The Hostname Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418423/the-hostname-regex)

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in your regex:

`[//]` - This is only one character, because the `[]` marks a character class, so it will not fully match `//`. To match it, you need to write it like this: `[/][/]` or `\/\/`.

`(.*)` - This will match all characters to the end of line. You need to be more specific if you want to go till a certain character. For example you could go to the colon by fetching all characters, which are not colons, like this: `([^:]*)`.

`:*` - This makes the colon optional. I guess you forgot to put a dot( every character ) after the colon, like this: `:.*`.

So here is your regex corrected: `\/\/([^:]*):.*`.

Hope this helps.

BTW. If the port number is optional after production (:5432), then I suggest the following regex:
`\/\/([^/]*)(?::\d+)?\/`

Answer (score 0):

To capture also Oracle and MySQL JDBC URL variants with their quirks (e.g. Oracle allowing to use `@` instead of `//` or even `@//`), I use this regexp to get the hostname: `[/@]+([^:/@]+)([:/]+|$)` Then the hostname is in group 1.

Code e.g.

```
String jdbcURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//hostname:1521/service.domain.local";
Pattern hostFinderPattern = Pattern.compile("[/@]+([^:/@]+)([:/]+|$)");
final Matcher match = hostFinderPattern.matcher(jdbcURL);
if (match.find()) {
  System.out.println(match.group(1));
}
```

This works for all these URLs (and other variants):

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//hostname:1521/service.domain.local
jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:1521/service.domain.local
jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname/service.domain.local
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila?profileSQL=true
jdbc:postgresql://production:5432/dbname
jdbc:postgresql://production/
jdbc:postgresql://production
```

This assumes that

- The hostname is after `//` or `@` or a combination thereof (single `/` would also work, but I don't think JDBC allows that).
- After the hostname either `:` or `/` or the end of the string follows.

Note that the the `+` are greedy, this is especially important for the middle one.