# Regex for extracting hostname

Tags: regex, pcre

Given a URL, I have to find the hostname by using a regex.

The URLs can be of varied forms:

```
http://www.google.com/                            [expected 'google.com']
https://www.google.com:2000/                      [expected 'www.google.com']
http://100.1.25.3:8000/foo/bar?abc.php=xxxx+xxxx  [expected '100.1.25.3']
www.google.com                                    [expected 'www.google.com']
10.0.2.2:5000                                     [expected '10.0.2.2']
localhost/                                        [expected 'localhost']
localhost/foo                                     [expected 'localhost']
```

The closest I could come up is with:

```
^(?:[^:]+://)*([^:/]+).*
```

and use the string captured by the first capturing group of the regular expression.

However, a few cases fail:

```
google.com   [nothing is captured, expected 'google.com']
http://///x  ['http' is captured, expected nothing]
```

What would be a regex that can cope up with these cases?

---

Please note that:

- I'm not asking what is wrong with my regex. I know where things are wrong, I just can't come up with another regex.
- Solutions only need to reliably extract the hostname, and need not validate it. I later on validate this stuff, so if the regex takes out `google!com` from `https://google!com/foo`, this is acceptable*.

<sup>* ... and probably even desirable, since hostnames can contain Unicode characters (Internationalized Domain Names).</sup>

Comment: Also show your expected output.

Comment: Seems to be very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418423/the-hostname-regex

Comment: why not use a uri handling library for this? re by all mean is not a suitable tool for this: https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this

```
/^(?:[a-zA-Z\d][a-zA-Z\d-]+){1}(?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})+$/
```

`^` - Indicates it must start with this regex

`(?:[a-zA-Z\d][a-zA-Z\d-]+){1}` - Matches the hostname

`(?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})+` - Matches one or more TLDs. `(co.uk)`

`$` - Indicates it must end with this regex

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but note that the simplest testcase (`google.com`) fails. You needn't do such a strict check, because I'll actually dealing with IDN hostnames, which have unicode characters! (edited to add that detail in the question).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex in PCRE:

```
'~^(?:[^:\n]+://)?([^:#/\n]*)~m'
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nA3sS9/1)