# Regular expression for host

Tags: regex

How can I match with regular expression hosts like **123-45-67-89.dummy37.ipx.northtelecom.net.uk** or **q6415-ipbffx02alas.tokyo.ocx.wa.jp**?

Additional info, some samples (I modified some hosts for privacy reasons):

- abc953.internetdsl.uwnet.pl
- ip-200-200-200-200.static.puxdsl.pt.lu
- 123-123-45-45.cost.xligtik.se
- saul-wilhem-c-118-37.sewl-net.com
- static-80-80-250-230.sdsl91.rokh.ny.premiernet.net
- static-ip-cr73415187.kable.net.ca

etc.

Host that must NOT match: e.g., hosts like `foo---bar.example.com` or `foo...bar.example.com`

**Solved**: I should have solved with the following pattern:

```
/((?:[a-z0-9\-]*\.){1,}[a-z0-9\-]*)/
```

Comment: Your suggested regex matches `foo...bar.example.com`, which you stated you must NOT match.

Comment: Well, I did not need to validate hostnames, but to catch in an existing log file. The above pattern was perfect for my job.

Answer (score 1):

A regular expression to match those hostnames might be:

```
[-.0-9a-z]+
```

However, that will probably match much more than you intend. You will have to be more specific about what exactly you want to match (and what you *don't* want to match).

Comment: That's correct, which is why I mentioned that the OP needs to be more precise about what *exactly* the regular expression should match.

Comment: @Paryeshakaya: That's great, but additional matching examples don't help define what you do want to match. Should the host `foo---bar.example.com` match? How about `foo...bar.example.com`? My point is that my answer is a *correct* answer to your question as stated, but it's almost completely useless. You will have to refine your question so that you are more precise about what you *do* and *don't* want to match with your regex.

Comment: All of your examples would be matched by both mine and Greg's expressions. The problem is going to be that mine and to a greater extent Greg's will match strings you *don't* want matched. Did you follow the link in Arno's reply? smink's response there (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-hostname-or-ip-address/106223#106223) looks really cool.

Comment: @Greg: thanks for your answers. No, hosts like foo---bar.example.com or foo...bar.example.com should not match

Comment: Then I don't know what rule you are using for determining what is a "valid" host name. The first example is a valid DNS hostname while the second is not.

Comment: The hosts are parsed in log files (like /var/log/secure and /var/log/messages). What I showed in my samples is what exactly I meet, I have changed only few chars or IP for privacy reason. I know that some of them are not valid DNS hostnames.

Comment: What I meant was that `foo---bar.example.com` is a valid DNS hostname, but `foo...bar.example.com` is not. This does not match your definition of what you want to accept and not accept, so I don't know what rule you are using to determine what is "valid". Without that information, nobody can create a regular expression for you until you can precisely state what you consider "valid".

Comment: See my comments above, I should have solved. Thanks again for support

Comment: Further note: I do not need to validate, but to match hostnames in an already existing log file

Answer (score 0):

In which language? The following should work in most

```
[a-z0-9-]+\([a-z0-9-.]+\)*
```

Comment: It should be used in a PHP script

Comment: I don't know PHP. You will need to check how grouping works, which I have used \\( and \\) for here. @arno's answer above http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524266/regular-expression-for-host/1524281#1524281 is probably more useful than mine.