# Is there an easy way to convert String to Inetaddress in Java?

Tags: java, string, inetaddress

I am trying to convert strings into `Inetaddress`. I am not trying to resolve hostnames: the strings are ipv4 addresses. Does `InetAddress.getByName(String host)` work? Or do I have to manually parse it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`com.google.common.net.InetAddresses.forString(String ipString)` is better for this as it will not do a DNS lookup regardless of what string is passed to it.

Comment: This is part [of Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/net/InetAddresses.html).

Comment: It should be `com.google.common.net.InetAddresses.forString` (with `InetAddresses` with uppercase A). SO won’t allow me to correct that in your answer, as the edit has to be at least 6 characters. ;-)

Anyway, thanks, was looking for it, and yet again Guava saves the day.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, that will work.  [The API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName%28java.lang.String%29) is very clear on this ("The host name can either be a machine name, such as "java.sun.com", or a textual representation of its IP address."), and of course you could easily check yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I looked up the api, and missed that line.

Comment: Whats when host is a pattern like 192.168.0.*? Will that work too? Regarding to Inet4Address doc there seems support for this.

Comment: @Paranaix, no, it will throw a `IllegalArgumentException` with the message "invalid host wildcard specification"

Comment: in particular, the documentation says: `If a literal IP address is supplied, only the validity of the address format is checked.` which I read as: 'if you specify a (dotted quad notation) IP address, no DNS lookup is performed'.

Comment: The OP said "I am not trying to resolve hostnames"; if the input to `getByName()` is not a valid numeric IP address, but is a valid resolvable DNS name, the name will be resolved. That does not seem to be what the OP wants.

Comment: @Raedwald, he also said "the strings are ipv4 addresses".  If the input is known to be just IP addresses, this should work fine.

Answer (score 3):

Beware: it seems that parsing an invalid address such as `InetAddress.getByName("999.999.999.999"`) will *not* result in an exception as one might expect from the documentation's phrase:

> the validity of the address format is checked

Empirically, I find myself getting an InetAddress instance with the local machine's raw IP address and the invalid IP address as the host name. Certainly this was not what I expected!

Comment: As of Java 7, this will throw an UnknownHostException; haven't checked earlier Javas, but I would expect an exception there as well.

Comment: @CraigTrader, but if you look at the stack trace you will see that this is not actually a parsing exception, but Java tries to look this up as host name, which is somewhat worrying.

Comment: Because `999.999.999.999` is NOT a valid IPv4 address, Java asks the system's name server to resolve it as a hostname. Since there is no valid DNS entry for that IP address, you'll get an `UnknownHostException`. If you try this with a valid IPv4 address, you'll get a valid `InetAddress` object.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [using a regular expression to filter-out non-numeric IP addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/q/106179/545127) before passing the `String` to `getByName()`. Then `getByName()` will not try name resolution.

Answer (score 0):

[The open-source IPAddress Java library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/) will validate all standard representations of IPv6 and IPv4 and will do so without DNS lookup.  Disclaimer: I am the project manager of that library.

The following code will do what you are requesting:

```
     String s = "1.2.3.4";
     try {
            IPAddressString str = new IPAddressString(s);
            IPAddress addr = str.toAddress();
            InetAddress inetAddress = addr.toInetAddress(); //IPv4 or IPv6
            if(addr.isIPv4() || addr.isIPv4Convertible()) {//IPv4 specific
                IPv4Address ipv4Addr = addr.toIPv4();
                Inet4Address inetAddr = ipv4Addr.toInetAddress();
                //use address
            }
      } catch(AddressStringException e) {
            //e.getMessage has validation error
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

With the DNSJava library, you can also parse it.

```java
InetAddress address = Address.getByAddress(ipString)
```

No external call, just using the `Address.toByteArray` method.

Answer (score 0):

Since [Java 22](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/net/InetAddress.html#ofLiteral(java.lang.String)):

```
jshell> InetAddress addr = InetAddress.ofLiteral("127.0.0.1")
addr ==> /127.0.0.1

jshell> InetAddress addr = InetAddress.ofLiteral("::0")
addr ==> /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0

jshell> InetAddress addr = InetAddress.ofLiteral("999.999.999.999")
|  Exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid IP address literal: 999.999.999.999
|        at IPAddressUtil.invalidIpAddressLiteral (IPAddressUtil.java:169)
|        at Inet6Address.ofLiteral (Inet6Address.java:534)
|        at InetAddress.ofLiteral (InetAddress.java:1735)
|        at (#7:1)
```