# Java: Convert a String (representing an IP) to InetAddress

Tags: java, ip, inetaddress

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an easy way to convert String to Inetaddress in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309049/is-there-an-easy-way-to-convert-string-to-inetaddress-in-java)

I'm  trying to convert a string(representing an IP address, e.g. `10.0.2.50`) into an `InetAddress` obj.

According to the API it is possible to create an Object providing a String representing a hostname (e.g. `www.google.ch`). This is not an option for me since I do not have the hostname for each InetAddress object I want to create(besides that it takes too long).

Is it possible to convert a String (e.g. `10.0.2.50`) into an `InetAddress` obj.? (according to the api it is possible to do so if you have the IP as `byte[]`, but how do I convert a `String` containing an IP into `byte[]`?)

Comment: Didn't find this one, it is indeed the same problem.

Answer (score 189, accepted):

Simply call [`InetAddress.getByName(String host)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName(java.lang.String)) passing in your textual IP address.

From the javadoc: The host name can either be a machine name, such as "java.sun.com", or a textual representation of its IP address.

Comment: thx! Looks like i skipped this part. sorry for that.

Comment: Those who use this please note that if the ip-adress are not valid the timeout for the lookup is long enough that when done repeatedly it causes the program to run slowly.

Comment: This is a bad idea if all you're intending to do is parse IP addresses, since getByName will also do hostname lookups.  If a hostname is passed to your function, you'll be doing synchronous network I/O where you didn't intend to be.

Comment: @GlennMaynard: the actual JDK code checks if the first character is a digit, and if yes, then just parses it using IPAddressUtil.

Comment: @AndrisBirkmanis But if someone passes in a hostname (eg. because you're parsing a configuration file or similar), that's not what will happen.  If you only intend to parse an IP address, then you should use a function that only parses IP addresses.

Comment: But this is not giving me as expected one.

Comment: `IPAddressUtil` in sun.net.util is best alternative. But we should be aware of this https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/faq-sun-packages.html

Comment: @GlennMaynard what is the alterntaive then?

Answer (score 19):

From the documentation of [`InetAddress.getByName(String host)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName(java.lang.String)):

> The host name can either be a machine
> name, such as "java.sun.com", or a
> textual representation of its IP
> address. If a literal IP address is
> supplied, only the validity of the
> address format is checked.

So you can use it.