# Converting string to IP Address in java(android)

Tags: java, android, sockets

When i convert string `("192.168.0.105")` to InetAddress in java (android). I am getting `"/192.168.0.105"`. An extra `"/"` is coming in InetAddress, which causes the socket not to be created.

How do i get rid of "/".

Regards,

Syed Mustehsan Ikram

Comment: it would help if you posted the code that isn't quite doing what you want

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571744/java-convert-a-string-representing-an-ip-to-inetaddress

Comment: How do you convert? `InetAddress.getByName("192.168.0.105");` ?

Comment: InetAddress = serverIP=Inet4Address.getByName(ip);

clientSocket = new Socket(serverIP , serverPort);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `getHostAddress()` method of [InetAddress](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getHostAddress%28%29) to get host address without `/`.

And if you are using `InetSocketAddress` then use `getAddress().getHostAddress()` to get host ip without `/`.

```
InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.0.105");
System.out.println(inetAddress.getHostAddress());

InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress("192.168.0.105", 5555);
System.out.println(address.getAddress().getHostAddress());
```

Comment: my problem is that i need to open Socket after getting InetAddress

Comment: @Mustehsan: in that case use java Socket to open and communicate through socket. Read this: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html and this: http://zerioh.tripod.com/ressources/sockets.html

Comment: I am currently doing it. but my problem is that as InetAddress is wrong thus socket is not being created.

Comment: I am getting following exception on socket creation java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Transport endpoint is not connected

Comment: @Mustehsan: are you sure ip is reachable?

Comment: make sure that ip is reachable and firewall has exception for that port no. i.e your allowed to connect to that port, so check firewall

Answer (score 2):

```
myString = myString.replace("/", "");
```