# How do I output my ip address as a string?

Tags: java, string, ip-address

I have been using InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress(), how would I get this as a string?

Comment: the getHostAddress() returns String value. Then else do you need to be in String format?

Comment: You've got as a String. Not a real question.

Answer (score 1):

To output an ip as string, from Justin Waugh's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571744/java-convert-a-string-representing-an-ip-to-inetaddress/5571816#5571816):

> Simply call `InetAddress.getByName(String host)` passing in your
>   textual IP address.
>
> From the javadoc: The host name can either be a machine name, such as
>   "java.sun.com", or a textual representation of its IP address.
>
> [InetAddress javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName%28java.lang.String%29)

Or use `InetAddress.getHostAddress()` as Nambari suggested.