# How to extract an IP address from an HTML string?

Tags: python, regex, string

I want to extract an IP address from a string (actually a one-line HTML) using Python.

```
>>> s = "<html><head><title>Current IP Check</title></head><body>Current IP Address: 165.91.15.131</body></html>"
```

-- '165.91.15.131' is what I want!

I tried using regular expressions, but so far I can only get to the first number.

```
>>> import re
>>> ip = re.findall( r'([0-9]+)(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', s )
>>> ip
['165']
```

But I don't have a firm grasp on reg-expression; the above code was found and modified from elsewhere on the web.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular expression to match hostname or IP Address?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-hostname-or-ip-address)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Remove your capturing group:

```
ip = re.findall( r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', s )
```

Result:

```
['165.91.15.131']
```

Notes:

- If you are parsing HTML it might be a good idea to look at [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).
- Your regular expression matches some invalid IP addresses such as `0.00.999.9999`. This isn't necessarily a problem, but you should be aware of it and possibly handle this situation. You could change the `+` to `{1,3}` for a partial fix without making the regular expression overly complex.

Comment: You can use the regex expression to accept only valid IP addresses "\\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\b"

Comment: Very nice. For those of you who were interested in the impact of (?:...), you can find it at the docs http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html : "(?:...)
A non-capturing version of regular parentheses. Matches whatever regular expression is inside the parentheses, but the substring matched by the group cannot be retrieved after performing a match or referenced later in the pattern."

Comment: @o0rebelious0o Impressive regexp. For easines and in case that you're already using this python solution, you could use `ipaddress.ip_address(ip)` to check for it.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following regex to capture only valid IP addresses

```
re.findall(r'\b25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?\.25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?\.25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?\.25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?\b',s)
```

returns

```
['165', '91', '15', '131']
```

Comment: Technically, this doesn't match valid IP adresses but valid octets. There can be any number of them, which might need to be checked in a separate step.

Answer (score 4):

```
import re

ipPattern = re.compile('\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}')

findIP = re.findall(ipPattern,s)

findIP contains ['165.91.15.131']
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use following regex to extract valid IP without following errors
1.Some detected `123.456.789.111` as valid IP
2.Some don't detect `127.0.00.1` as valid IP
3.Some don't detect IP that start with zero like `08.8.8.8`

So here I post a regex that works on all above conditions.

> Note : I have extracted more than 2 millions IP without any problem with following regex.

```
(?:(?:1\d\d|2[0-5][0-5]|2[0-4]\d|0?[1-9]\d|0?0?\d)\.){3}(?:1\d\d|2[0-5][0-5]|2[0-4]\d|0?[1-9]\d|0?0?\d)
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your `regex pattern` ??

Comment: @MohammadZainAbbas. I think it would be a so long reply. Feel free to enjoy this interactive explanation -> https://regexr.com/4r3j3

Answer (score 2):

easiest way to find the ip address from the log..

```
 s = "<html><head><title>Current IP Check</title></head><body>Current IP Address: 165.91.15.131</body></html>"
 info = re.findall(r'[\d.-]+', s)
```

> In [42]: info
>
> Out[42]: ['165.91.15.131']

Comment: Could you please explain this [\d.-]+ ,  '- after . what it will represent

Comment: `[\d.-]+` will grab any number even if the string doesn't contains IPs, i.e: it will grab the IP and the numbers `1` & `2` in a sentence like `104.108.71.62: has versionsr: 1 vs. 2`

Answer (score 1):

This is how I've done it. I think it's so clean

```
import re
import urllib2

def getIP():
    ip_checker_url = "http://checkip.dyndns.org/"
    address_regexp = re.compile ('\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}')
    response = urllib2.urlopen(ip_checker_url).read()
    result = address_regexp.search(response)

    if result:
            return result.group()
    else:
            return None
```

get_IP() returns ip into a string or None

You can substitute address_regexp for other regular expressions if you prefer a more accurate parsing or maybe change the web service provider.