# How do I find a pattern like 252.63.71.62 in a text in Python with re(gex)?

Tags: python, regex

I have a webpage, from which I get its text using the resources module in Python. But, I'm not getting it, how to get a pattern of numbers like 126.23.73.34 from the document and extract it out using the re module?

Comment: if you want to extract IP, this could help -> 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890896/extract-ip-address-from-an-html-string-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the regex for IPs `d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}`

```
text = "126.23.73.34";
match = re.search(r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}', text)
if match:
   print "match.group(1) : ", match.group(0)
```

If you are looking for a complete regex to get IPv4 addresses you can find the most appropriate regex [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html).

To restrict all 4 numbers in the IP address to 0-255, you can use this one taken from the source above:

```
(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)
```

Comment: This is the correct regex for IPv4 addresses btw: `\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b`

Comment: Yep. I wasn't sure if he was looking for an IP, but I assumed as much. I'll include a link as a reference.

Comment: I'm not sure the format of your answer result is what the OP would want, see: C:\wamp\www>Example.py
('192', '168', '0', '1')
('192', '168', '0', '254')

Comment: @o0rebelious0o try `print match.group()`

Answer (score 1):

If if it is an html text; you could use an html parser (such as [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)) to parse it, a regex to select some strings that look like an ip, and `socket` module to validate ips:

```
import re
import socket
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # pip install beautifulsoup4

def isvalid(addr):
    try:
        socket.inet_aton(addr)
    except socket.error:
        return False
    else:
        return True

soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage)
ipre = re.compile(r"\b\d+(?:\.\d+){3}\b") # matches some ips and more
ip_addresses = [ip for ips in map(ipre.findall, soup(text=ipre))
                for ip in ips if isvalid(ip)]
```

Note: it extracts ips only from text e.g., it ignores ips in html attributes.

Comment: @Sazid: It is a library that you can use to extract info from HTML text. I've added link to its docs

Answer (score 0):

You can use this. It will only accept **VALID** IP addresses:

```
import re
pattern = "\\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\b"
text = "192.168.0.1 my other IP is 192.168.0.254 but this one isn't a real ip 555.555.555.555"
m = re.findall(pattern, text)
for i in m :
    print(i)
```

OUTPUT:

```
C:\wamp\www>Example.py
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.254
```

--Tested and working

Comment: Sure that works, but what if it is not a valid IP? e.g. 555.168.0.1?

Comment: The question is, and I quote, "get a pattern of numbers like 126.23.73.34 from the document and extract it"  It didn't say anything about actually validating the extracted values

Comment: That doesn't mean that other people won't look at this question a month, or year from now. It is always in the best interest of the community to provide the most complete answer possible.