# Python get IP address from telnetlib output

Tags: python, regex

Using telnetlib I pull routing info from my router and want to extract the WAN IP address using a pattern. The output of the telnet session is in a variable with lines separated by \n.

The stuff from the telnet session.

```
l= tn.read_all()
>>> l
'\r\nip -f inet addr\r\nexit\r\nadmin4asus@RT-AC68U:/tmp/home/root# ip -f inet addr\r\n1: lo: <LOOPBACK,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN \r\n    inet 127.0.0.1/8 brd 127.255.255.255 scope host lo\r\n2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 1000\r\n    inet 24.6.29.214/21 brd 24.6.31.255 scope global eth0\r\n7: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,ALLMULTI,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN \r\n    inet 192.168.11.1/24 brd 192.168.11.255 scope global br0\r\n8: tun21: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 100\r\n    inet 10.8.0.1 peer 10.8.0.2/32 scope global tun21\r\nadmin4asus@RT-AC68U:/tmp/home/root# exit\r\n'
>>>
```

Now my code.

```
l= tn.read_all()
for line in l.split('\n'):
    match= re.findall( r'([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}).*scope global eth0', line)
    if match is not None:
        print('Found ' + line)
```

I would have expected the one line that matches to print.

```
Found     inet 24.6.29.214/21 brd 24.6.31.255 scope global eth0
```

But I get the find everywhere.

```
Found 
Found ip -f inet addr
Found exit
Found admin4asus@RT-AC68U:/tmp/home/root# ip -f inet addr
Found 1: lo: <LOOPBACK,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
Found     inet 127.0.0.1/8 brd 127.255.255.255 scope host lo
Found 2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
Found     inet 24.6.29.214/21 brd 24.6.31.255 scope global eth0
Found 7: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,ALLMULTI,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
Found     inet 192.168.11.1/24 brd 192.168.11.255 scope global br0
Found 8: tun21: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 100
Found     inet 10.8.0.1 peer 10.8.0.2/32 scope global tun21
Found admin4asus@RT-AC68U:/tmp/home/root# exit
Found
```

I can't figure out why my code is failing. If the experts have a better method (with explanation) that would be great.

**Edit :**

Jan's answer is surely more pythonic, but my lack of knowledge of python makes me prefer vks which is easier to understand for me.  I gave both a '^' and will mark vks as preferred (in the sense 'preferred by me').

I ended up using '\r\n' in the 'split' cmd and following code.

```
def get_asus_wan_ip():
    "Gets WAN IP from ASUS router"

    import telnetlib
    import re

    ASUS_IP=   '192.168.1.1'
    ASUS_USER= 'xxxxxxxx'
    ASUS_PASS= 'yyyyyyyy'
    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(ASUS_IP)

    tn.read_until("login: ")
    tn.write(ASUS_USER + "\n")
    tn.read_until("Password: ")
    tn.write(ASUS_PASS + "\n")
    tn.write("ifconfig eth0\n")
    tn.write("exit\n")
    l= tn.read_all()
    for line in l.split('\r\n'):
        match= re.findall( r'^\s+inet addr:([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}).*', line)
        if match:
            break

    wan_ip= match[0]
    return wan_ip
```

Comment: ``re.findall()`` returns a *list* of matches.  The list can be empty; it cannot possibly be ``None``.  For a single match, you want ``re.search()`` (or re.match()`` if the match has to be at the start of the string).

Comment: Your [**regex works fine**](https://regex101.com/r/rfgo3G/1) (slightly tuned), the `if` construction is the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract IP address from an html string (python)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890896/extract-ip-address-from-an-html-string-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import re
x="""'\r\nip -f inet addr\r\nexit\r\nadmin4asus@RT-AC68U:/tmp/home/root# ip -f inet addr\r\n1: lo: <LOOPBACK,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN \r\n    inet 127.0.0.1/8 brd 127.255.255.255 scope host lo\r\n2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 1000\r\n    inet 24.6.29.214/21 brd 24.6.31.255 scope global eth0\r\n7: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,ALLMULTI,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN \r\n    inet 192.168.11.1/24 brd 192.168.11.255 scope global br0\r\n8: tun21: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 100\r\n    inet 10.8.0.1 peer 10.8.0.2/32 scope global tun21\r\nadmin4asus@RT-AC68U:/tmp/home/root# exit\r\n'"""
for line in x.split('\n'):
    match= re.findall(r'(?:[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}).*scope global eth0', line)
    if match:
        print('Found ' + line)
```

Output:`Found     inet 24.6.29.214/21 brd 24.6.31.255 scope global eth0`

Problems with your code:

1) `re.findall` returns `list` , so it cannot be `None` it can be empty.So use that in `if` condition.

2) `re.findall` returns only groups if there are some.If you want the whole line, make the first group non capturing.

Answer (score 2):

You could vastly shrink your code with a list comprehension:

```
import re

string = """
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 brd 127.255.255.255 scope host lo
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    inet 24.6.29.214/21 brd 24.6.31.255 scope global eth0
7: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,ALLMULTI,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    inet 192.168.11.1/24 brd 192.168.11.255 scope global br0
8: tun21: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 100
    inet 10.8.0.1 peer 10.8.0.2/32 scope global tun21
"""

rx = re.compile(r'\b(\d+(?:\.\d+){3})\b.*scope global eth0')
matches = [line
            for line in string.split("\n")
            for match in [rx.search(line)]
            if match]
print(matches)
# ['    inet 24.6.29.214/21 brd 24.6.31.255 scope global eth0']
```

Or if you prefer `filter()` and `lambda()`:

```
matches = list(filter(lambda x: rx.search(x), string.split("\n")))
print(matches)
```