# Extracting the Server Name \Ip from the Description using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a column called Description in my Dataframe. I have text in that column as below.

## Description

```
Summary: SD1: Low free LOG space in database saptempdb: 2.99% Date: 01/01/2017 Severity: Major Reso
Summary: SD1: Low free DATA space in database 10:101:101:1 2.99% Date: 01/01/2017 Severity: Major Res
Summary: SAP SolMan Sys=SM1_SNG01AMMSOL04,MO=AGEEPM40,Alert=Columnstore Unloads,Desc= ,Cat=Exception
```

How to extract the Server name or IPs fro  the above description. I have around 10000 rows.

I have written as below, to split the senetences as comma separated. Now I need to filter the server names or ips

```
    df['sentsplit'] = df["Description"].str.split(" ")
    print df
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890896/extract-ip-address-from-an-html-string-python

Comment: Thanks Shreyas. This will work for IPs. What about the Server names ?  Eg: saptempdb, SM1_SNG01AMMSOL04

Comment: Yes, what about server names?

Comment: @ ShreyasG  That's where I am stuck.

Comment: Search for this patter and split by ':', to get the server name? `\S+: \d+.\d+%`

Comment: hostip = re.compile(r'\S+:\d+.\d+%,')
        for line in df['Short Description']:
            print hostip.match(line)                                                                                  Tried above code, I get None as result

Answer (score 0):

The general case of what you're asking is "How do I parse this input?".  The task then is what knowledge of your input can you exploit to answer your question?  Do all the lines follow one or a few forms?  Can you place any restrictions on where the hostname or IP address will be on each line?

Given your input, here's a regex I might apply.  Quick and dirty -- not elegant -- but if it's only for 10,000 lines, and a one-off job, who cares?  It's functional:

```
database (\d+:\d+:\d+:\d+)|database (\w+)|Sys=([^, ]+),
```

This regex assumes that the IP address will always be after the word `database` and preceded by a space, OR that the hostname will be after the word `database, OR that the hostname will be preceded by`Sys=`and followed by a`,` or a space.

Obviously, test for your purposes, and fine tune as appropriate.  In the Python API:

```
host_or_ip_re = re.compile(r'database (\d+:\d+:\d+:\d+)|database (\w+)|Sys=([^, ]+),')
for line in log:
    m = host_or_ip_re.searc( line )
    if m:
        print m.groups()
```

The detail that always trips me up is the difference between `match` and `search`.  [Match *only* matches from the beginning of the string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I agree your point.
# First things #: - In most fo the rows, the IPs and the Servernames doesnt start after the word 'database' or 'preceded by' Sys=.
#Secondly# I am just doing a POC for 10,000 records. But in Real time scenario, It could be more lakhs of data.