# Have to find IP address OR IP address pattern in string

Tags: regex, python-3.x, numbers, ip-address

I have a below and many more below like strings in list.. I have to extract the IP addresses only from each string.

"Below server have been decommissioned via # C180013538  & C180025327  request.
Please remove any firewall rules associated with this server, So that the IP\'s can be re-used in the future. 
Please refer attachment for FW rules removal server details.", \'Server Details :- \', \'ServerName   IP Address\', \'CHIIUGA06RR
       10.103.225.37\', \'CICCKDBP11VE   10.103.113.11\', \'CICCKDBP12VE   10.103.113.13\
/"

Expected Result : -
10.103.225.37
10.103.113.11
10.103.113.13

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890896/extract-ip-address-from-an-html-string-python

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

list = ["\'Server Details :- \', \'ServerName IP Address\', \'CHIIUGA06RR 10.103.225.37\', \'CICCKDBP11VE 10.103.113.11\', \'CICCKDBP12VE 10.103.113.13\ /", 
"\'Server Details :- \', \'ServerName IP Address\', \'CHIIUGA06RR 10.103.225.37\', \'CICCKDBP11VE 10.103.113.11\', \'CICCKDBP12VE 10.103.113.13\ /"]

for s in list:
    print re.findall( r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}',  s)
```

See: [Extract IP address from an html string (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890896/extract-ip-address-from-an-html-string-python)