# Validate a user-entered IP address or hostname via C#

Tags: c#, regex, winforms, data-entry

In a couple of fields in my Windows Forms application, I am asking a user to supply either an IP address or a hostname. Is there a good regular expression (regex) to validate the entered value? Or is there another method that I should consider? Please note I would prefer that the user enters a [FQDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) or an IP address.

Comment: Don't forget to consider the implications of IPv6 addresses if you want this application to last.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular expression to match hostname or IP Address?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-hostname-or-ip-address)

Comment: jjnguy - Did not mean to repost. I will check this out and my apologies if i did.

Dave - been looking at that aspect myself and realize that I may be going down the wrong path in my app at the moment since it is current based only on IPv4. Am very worried about that.

Comment: Added "Or is there another method that I should consider?" since you were receptive to a non-regex approach. That also keeps this question from being flagged as a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the interest of future-proofing your application, I'd suggest just using `IPAddress.TryParse()` to determine if the input is an IP address.

Checking for a 'valid' hostname is more difficult, also because you didn't specify whether the hostname has to exist or not. If it does, the easiest way would be to use `Dns.GetHostEntry()` to see if that yields a result. You can't get much more accurate validation based on the description you gave.

Comment: Would Dns.GetHostEntry() be useful if the user typed in a host and then clicked on a button to validate the host entry...like the Check Names button on Active Directory related fields?

Comment: Certainly, I've seen this done in multiple tools, the first that springs to mind is IIS SMTP Server Config (when setting the server's FQDN).

Comment: See [IPAddress.AddressFamily](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.addressfamily.aspx) to distinguish between an IPv4 and IPv6 address. Also see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/53500/1497596).

Answer (score 1):

try to call [IPAddress.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.tryparse.aspx) , if it fails try to [Dns.GetHostByName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostbyname.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you like to validate if the format is valid, you can use

```
bool isValid = Uri.CheckHostName(hostname) == UriHostNameType.Dns;
```

instead of Regex, wich can be error-prone. I use this in a pre-configuration application, where the user can specify a hostname which will be set in the *future*. For this purpose, [`Dns.GetHostEntry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.net.dns.gethostentry?view=net-6.0) is not suiteable because it trys to resolve the hostname, which will fail since it's not assigned yet.

So it depends on your needs. If the user should enter a hostname who actually can be resolved, you may want to use [`Dns.GetHostEntry()` or `IPAddress.TryParse()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3061664/3276634). If you just want to do input validation, try `Uri.CheckHostName`.

Comment: Checking for single word like Uri.CheckHostName("name") is also valid since it's valid for local network, so for internet addresses it's also required to check if there is at least 1 dot and that it's not at the end, since "name." is also valid

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need to ask for the IP address and for the hostname for a Windows Form application? If these are the local PC details, you could get these from:-

1) To get the hostname, you can call **Dns.GetHostName()** (see [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostname.aspx))

2) To get the IP address, you can enumerate the IP address via **Dns.GetHostByName()** (see [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostbyname.aspx))

Comment: The data would not be used to test things out on the local system. It would be used to determine whether a SSH server exists and also whether the data a user enters is real (as in blahblahblah == wrong, 66.234.34.23 == correct). This question is dealing completely with remote hosts.

Comment: @ThaKidd, thank you for the clarification. On the note, I think you can still use Dns.GetHostByName(hostname) to verify if the hostname is valid. Ditto for the the IP address which you can use Dns.GetHostByAddress() to check the address.

Comment: Dns.GetHostByName and Dns.GetHostByAddress have both been marked obsolete.