# Validating DNS with Regex

Tags: c#, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regular expression to match hostname or IP Address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-hostname-or-ip-address)

I need to validate a string that should contain DNS. Which regex is appropiate?

Comment: You need to be more specific; the phrase "contains DNS" is not well-defined. Are you talking about `A` records?

Comment: @Kaan - That's an IP... one of google's free DNS service nodes, specifically ;)

Comment: @Nick, it can also be a ip or a domain :)..

Comment: @Kaan - No...it can't, `.8` is not a TLD...

Comment: @Nick, I mean changing DNS server of an adapter in PCs..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems someone asks this question yet, try to search before asking see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-hostname-or-ip-address)

Answer (score 4):

This regex should work:   `.*DNS.*`

Comment: Yes but I got two down votes on it. :-(

Answer (score 2):

Using regexlib works wonders!

http://www.regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=dns

Answer (score 0):

```
(?=^.{1,254}$)(^(?:(?!\d+\.|-)[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]{1,63}(?<!-)\.?)+(?:[a-zA-Z]{2,})$)
```