# regular expression to parse IP

Tags: regex

I am after a regular expression to parse IP addresses and extract their host, port, username, and password.

Here are the formats I am interested in:

- 12.34.56.789
- http://12.34.56.789:80
- http://12.34.56.789
- 12.34.56.789:80
- http://login:password@12.34.56.789:80

Comment: `http://…` is not an IP address but a URI.

Comment: 789 is not a valid octet. Also: what have you tried so far?

Comment: What language are you using? Chances are there's already a better solution than writing your own regular expression

Comment: you may find a similar question from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-hostname-or-ip-address

Comment: So much for RFC 1738’s forbidding of embedding of HTTP authentication  in URLs.

Comment: Gumbo, Matt, tchrist: that may be true, but this is the data I need to work with

Comment: zomboid: that example is just for validating an IP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start with that (python):

```
import re

pattern = "((?P<login>\w+):(?P<password>\w+)@)?(?P<ip>\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3})(:(?P<port>\d+))?"

re.match(pattern, "12.34.56.789").groupdict()
re.match(pattern, "12.34.56.789:80").groupdict()
re.match(pattern, "john:pass@12.34.56.789:80").groupdict()
```

And obviously, the IP you specified is not valid (as Matt says ...)

Comment: Worth to note that this parses invalid IPs and ports too, i.e: `999.999.999.999:000000222222222`. So this solution is great for use in vacuum.

Answer (score 7):

Try something like this

```
(http://(\w+:\w+@)?)?(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}(:\d{1,5})?
```

Explanation:

```
(http://(\w+:\w+@)?)? - optional group of http:// followed by optional user:pass@
(\d{1,3}\.){3} - three groups of one to three digits followed by a dot
\d{1,3} - one to three digits
(:\d{1,5})? - optional group of colon followed by one to five digits
```

Comment: it would be much better if u specified that ip is a number in (1-255) not starts by 0 and greater than 255..

Comment: Yes it is not very robust. See the link provided by Merlyn for some examples of how to only allow certain combinations of digits if needed.

Comment: +1, I have a good chunk of this implementation in my answer (which I figured out on my own), but I "debugged" it by comparing to this answer ;) (I had the username:password@ syntax backwards, lol).  This one is still better, though - I prefer the \w, and mine doesn't have the optional http://.  The explanation is also cleaner.

Answer (score 4):

Doing the match this way may not be a best practice.  It might be better to plug into some sort of code with *real* smarts in it, that can do general-purpose URI parsing.  If you have limited needs, though, and can comment/document thoroughly that your code will break if you demand more of it, then maybe it makes sense to go down this path.

The simplest way is to match four sets of 1 to 3 digits, with:

- optionally, one-or-more not-:, plus :, plus one-or-more not-@, plus @
- optionally, :, plus 1 to 5 digits

Something like:

```
([^:]+:[^@]+@)?(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}(:\d{1,5})?
```

But this would accept silly stuff, like "999.999.999.999:99999"

If you only want to accept *valid* IP addresses, and don't care that it happens to be part of a URI, or don't care what other garbage exists in the string, here is an example:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html

It basically matches four sets of:

- 2, plus 0-4, plus 0-9
- or 2, plus 5, plus 0-5
- or 1, plus 0-9, plus 0-9
- or 1-9, plus 0-9
- or 0-9

That should get you started.

- optionally, one-or-more not-:, plus :, plus one-or-more not-@, plus @ (max lengths may be interesting, here)
- optionally, :, plus 0-65535 (this I'll leave up to you, based on the 0-255 rules above)

There are other range-based rules for matching IP addresses that you might want to avoid (stuff like 0.0.0.0, and reserved ranges), but it may be easier to do subsequent matching for these.

Basically, I'd suggest you use the very-simple example, or plug into a library.

Comment: That would benefit tremendously from being in `(?x)` mode so you can get some elbowroom for cognitive chunking even if you don’t include actual comments.

Comment: @tchrist: I have no idea what you're talking about, but it sounds interesting :)  Is this in reference to perl?  grep?

Comment: Many regex engines allow you to use whitespace and comments in your patterns if you include a `/x` or embed `(?x)`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a small script whipped up in perl that does the following things
a) Strips out username and password after checking that the former starts with a character
b) Validates ip address
c) validated port

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

    while (<>) {
    chomp;
            if (/(?:(?:([a-zA-z]\w+)\:(\w+))@)?((\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3}))(?:\:(\d{1,5}))?/) {
                    print "username=$1\n";
                    print "password=$2\n";
                    print "ip address=$3\n";
                    print "port=$8\n";
                    print "Warning: IP Address invalid\n" if ($4>255||$5>255||$6>255||$7>255);
                    print "Warning: Port Address invalid\n" if ($8>65535);
            }
    }
```

**EDIT**: Recommendation from [tchrist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/471272/tchrist) below

Comment: You don’t need to mention `\d` if you already have `\w`: it’s redundant.

Comment: You can write `[\w]+` just as `\w+` now that you don't have two things to select from.  Also, `[a‑z][A‑Z]` *might* be better written as any character with the Unicode "Letter" property, which is `\p{Letter}` or `\pL` for short.

Comment: If it were me, I’d also escape the `@` just out of sheer reflex, even though Perl doesn't make you.

Comment: Was just looking into your other post re handling unicode. Will get my head around working with unicode in perl and then update this as per your recommendation. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

[Regexlib](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=IP%20address) would be a helpful resource for your question. You can find many solutions (May be you will need to combine some)

Answer (score 0):

for match exclusively a valid IP adress use

```
(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}
```

instead of

```
([01]?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(\.([01]?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3}
```

because many regex engine match the first possibility in the OR sequence

you can try your regex engine : 10.48.0.200