# How to modify regular expression for ip:port?

Tags: regex, python-2.7, ip-address

I have regular expression like

```
match = re.findall(r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', source)
```

It works fine to take something like 192.168.1.1 from source string.
How I can modify this regular expression for make it work with something like this:

```
192.168.1.1:80
```

Thank You for help.

P.S. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085128/regular-expression-to-parse-ip

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This will match IP addresses with ports numbers.

```
match = re.findall(r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}:[0-9]+', source)
```

If you want to make it flexible to match IP address without the ports and With the ports, you can use:

```
match = re.findall(r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}(:[0-9]+)?', source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the highest port number (**(2^16 - 1) or 65,535**) is not taken into account (in the solution above), this should be the regular expression for your case:

```
^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[0-9]{1,2})(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[0-9]{1,2})){3}(:((6553[0-5])|(655[0-2][0-9])|(65[0-4][0-9]{2})|(6[0-4][0-9]{3})|([1-5][0-9]{4})|([0-5]{1,5})|([0-9]{1,4})))?$|^$
```