# Validate whether a string is valid for IP Address or not

Tags: c#, string

As title, I want to validate whether a string is valid for IP Address or not in C#, and I've used

```
IPAddress.TryParse(value out address)
```

but it seems not so "Accurate", which means if I enter `"500"`, the address will be `"0.0.1.244"`, so its "Valid".

However, the form I'd like to accept is like `"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"`, and each term is less than `256`. Is there any API or method could achieve this?

Comment: u can create ur custom method.. and u can use this parse method there.

Comment: look at this answer for regex http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890789/regex-for-an-ip-address, also tye using IPAddress.TryParse in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.tryparse.aspx

Comment: Off-topic, but while designing new code, you should account for IPv6, too.

Comment: not that i have tried anything but couldnt regex be of help here?

Comment: Might be of interest: [IPv4AddressHelper](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/_IPv4Address.cs,6d6c0ff213882939)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pretty straightforward check it: split string to parts separated by dot and ensure it will be exactly four parts having values in range 1...255:

```
string s = "123.123.123.123";

var parts = s.Split('.');

bool isValid = parts.Length == 4
               && !parts.Any(
                   x =>
                   {
                       int y;
                       return Int32.TryParse(x, out y) && y > 255 || y < 1;
                   });
```

Comment: Thanks! I think its exactly what I want.

Comment: on "a12.123.123.123" it will fail, and not return false

Comment: @ArsenMkrtchyan reasonable. It will throw exception though. Have modified the code.

Comment: Also I think condition should be like this Int32.TryParse(x, out y) && y >= 1 && y < 255

Comment: @ArsenMkrtchyan disagreed. Have a look here: `!parts.Any(` and notice negation operator.

Comment: This fails to validate addresses containing 0. i.e. 192.168.0.1. You would need to check the first and fourth elements independently.

Answer (score 4):

Something like that:

```
private static Boolean IsIP(String value) {
  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    return false;

  var items = value.Split('.');

  if (items.Length != 4)
    return false;

  // Simplest: you may want use, say, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier to allow hex as well
  return items.All(item => byte.TryParse(item, out _));
}
```

Comment: Frankly, checking each part of address with `Byte.TryParse` is not sufficient, since 0 will be successfully parsed as byte, so this will consider "0.0.1.244" as valid address.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev `0` is valid. Ever heard of `127.0.0.1`?

Answer (score 3):

If you dont rely on TryParse here is one way to match for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

```
public static bool MyIP(string value)
    {
        var x = value.Split('.');
        if (!(x.Length==4)) 
           return false;

        foreach(var i in x) 
        {
            int q;
            if (!Int32.TryParse(x, out q)||q.ToString().Length.Equals(x.Length) 
                || q < 0 || q > 255) 
            { 
               return false;  
            }

        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: what is y? where is it defined or declared

Comment: you still have y.Length, please fix it.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd rather not do the parsing yourself the NuGet package [IPAddressRange](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IPAddressRange/) will do it for you. It has the advantage of supporting IPv6 addresses as well.

You can check out the [source code and documentation here](https://github.com/jsakamoto/ipaddressrange).

Answer (score -1):

```
string addrString = "192.168.0.1";
IPAddress address;
if (IPAddress.TryParse(addrString, out address)) {
       //Valid IP, with address containing the IP
} else {
       //Invalid IP
}
```

Comment: It's always a good idea to add some explanation to your solution.

Comment: K sir i will keep it in mind and follow next time while answering someone else questions

Answer (score -1):

You could try what you are already doing, with a short test before hand to ensure there are the correct number of "."s in the string.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.tryparse.aspx

It will determine if string is valid IPv4 address, this will not work for IPv6:

```
var stringToCheck = "192.168.1.1";
var countDots = stringToCheck.Split('.').Length - 1;
if (countDots==3)
{
    IPAddress validIpAddress;
    if (IPAddress.TryParse(stringToCheck, out validIpAddress))
    {
        //Valid IP, with validIpAddress containing the IP
        Console.WriteLine("Valid IP");
    }
    else
    {
        //Invalid IP
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid IP");
    }
}
else
{
    // Invalid as no "." in string, not even worth checking
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid IP not correct number Dots");
}
```

Comment: It is indeed returning `true` for `"500"` which is most certainly not a vaild IP address.

Comment: I've edited my answer, to check for a "." in the stringToCheck