# Extract delimited list from inside curly brackets

Tags: c#, arrays, regex

I have string input from a file that looks like this, and I have created a regex that successfully extracts just this:

```
 addresses { 1.1.1.1;
  2.2.2.2;
  3.3.3.3;
 }
```

And there can be arbitrary whitespace on any line. I'd like to get a `List<string>` of just the address values:

```
s[0] = "1.1.1.1"
s[1] = "2.2.2.2"
etc...
```

Can anyone help me with the relevant C#? I'm at the limits of my regex skills.

Comment: It's not clear what is wrong with your code. Do you have some error?

Comment: Take a look at this.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890789/regex-for-an-ip-address

Comment: what you have tried? anyway you could solve it with regex (again) and match the pattern `1.1.1.1` --> loooks like `(\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+);`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need just get content of curly braces (either with regex or simply with IndexOf) and split it by `;`

```
var input = @"addresses { 1.1.1.1; 2.2.2.2; 3.3.3.3; }";
var regex = new Regex(@"[^{]+{([^}]+)}", RegexOptions.Multiline);
var addresses = regex.Match(input).Groups[1].Value
    .Split(';')
    .Select(s => s.Trim())
    .Where(s => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Exactly the kind of elegant solution I was hoping to create. I had so much trouble with the proper syntax. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There could be n Number of ways you can extract the values from the string. This could be one of them.

```
string input = @"addresses { 1.1.1.1; 2.2.2.2; 3.3.3.3; }";
string formattedInput = Regex.Replace(input, @"[A-Za-z*{}]", "");
List<string> InpList = formattedInput.Split(new char[] { ' ', ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
```