# Url regex tweak to just capture url not ip

Tags: regex, go, url, regex-group

I have made this regex to capture all types of `url` (it literally capture all `url`) but it also captures single `ip`.

This is my scenario: I have a list full of IP, Hash and url and my url regex and ip regex both capture the same entry. I don't know if a single ip can be considered as "url".

My regex: `((http|https)://)?(www)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,9}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\|+.~#?&//={};,\[\]'"$\x60]*)?`

Captures all these:

```
http://127.0.0.1/
http://127.0.0.1
https://127.0.0.1/m=weblogin/loginform238,363,771,89816356,2167
127.0.0.1:8080 ------> excluding this one is okay too (optional)
127.0.0.1 ------> i want to exclude this one
google.com
google.com:80
www.google.com
https://google.com
https://www.google.com
```

I want my regex to capture all url's except single ip's like this:

```
127.0.0.1
```

- **Note**: I want to use this in golang code (using **golang regex engine**)
- **Note**: I am using `regexp.Compile()` and `FindAllString` functions.

[try this regex on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/y7CUnS/2)

Comment: The simplest way is to filter out those strings from the result that match [IP regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30023010/3832970).

Comment: Another way is to use [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/JnVAwQ/1) with [`FindAllStringSubmatch`](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.FindAllStringSubmatch) and only keep the Group 1 values.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It gets tricky because filtering with a `ip regex` might match `http://127.0.0.1` as well. However it seems like a solution worth trying, tnx.

Comment: Well, extend the IP matching part, see https://regex101.com/r/JnVAwQ/2

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Im working on your 2nd comment. Can u post a answer so i can accept it? I cannot even upvote your comment LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex implementing the ["best trick ever"](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick) with [`FindAllStringSubmatch`](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.FindAllStringSubmatch): match what you need to skip/omit, and match and *capture* what you need to keep.

```
\b(?:https?://)?(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b(?:[^:]|$)|((?:https?://)?(?:www)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,9}\b[-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\|+.~#?&//={};,\[\]'"$\x60]*)
```

The first alternative is an [IP matching regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30023010/3832970) where I added `(?:https?://)?` part to match an optional protocol part and `(?:[^:]|$)` part to make sure there is a char other than `:` or end of string immediately after the IP pattern, but you may further adjust this part.

Then, [use it in Go](https://play.golang.org/p/q8o_5kXZkoP) like

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    r := regexp.MustCompile(`\b(?:https?://)?(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b(?:[^:]|$)|((?:https?://)?(?:www)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,9}\b[-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\|+.~#?&//={};,\[\]'"$\x60]*)`)
    matches := r.FindAllStringSubmatch(`http://127.0.0.1/
http://127.0.0.1
http://www.127.0.0.1/m=weblogin/loginform238,363,771,89816356,2167
127.0.0.1:8080
127.0.0.1
google.com
google.com:80
www.google.com
https://google.com
https://www.google.com`, -1)
        for _, v := range matches {
            if (len(v[1]) > 0) {       // if Group 1 matched
            fmt.Println(v[1])          // Display it, else do nothing
        }
    }   
}
```

Output:

```
http://www.127.0.0.1/m=weblogin/loginform238,363,771,89816356,2167
127.0.0.1:8080
google.com
google.com:80
www.google.com
https://google.com
https://www.google.com
```