# Get object from a file using Powershell

Tags: powershell, loops

I've got a plain text file called `inputs.txt` with the following content:

```
some_array = {
  "x" = "blabla1"
  "y" = "blabla2"
  "z" = "blabla3"
}
ip_addresses = {
  "x" = "1.2.3.4"
  "y" = "1.2.3.4"
  "z" = "1.2.3.4"
}
names = {
  "x" = "abc"
  "y" = "def"
  "z" = "ghi"
}
```

... and many more of the same type of arrays.

Now I need to use PowerShell to loop through the IP addresses in the object ip_addresses.

I'm not really coming any further than:

```
$file = Get-Content -Path ./inputs.txt
```

Which will return the entire file, but I just need the IP addresses. Prefereably comma seperated.

Is there an easy way to loop though this? It would have been easier if `input.txt` were json files but they're not unfortunately. This is the structure and it can't be changed.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Can you not format inputs.txt as JSON or XML instead?  That might make life easier....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `switch` for this:

```
$collectIPs = $false
$ipAddresses = switch -Regex -File 'D:\Test\inputs.txt' {
    '^ip_addresses\s*=' { $collectIPs = $true }
    '^}' {$collectIPs = $false }
    default {
        if ($collectIPs) { ($_ -split '=')[-1].Trim(' "') }
    }
}

$ipAddresses -join ', '
```

Output:

```
1.2.3.4, 1.2.3.4, 1.2.3.4
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure with `Json` this would be easier.

```
$start = $false
$IPs = Get-Content -Path ./inputs.txt | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -match "}") {
        $start = $false
    }

    if ($start) {
        $arr = $_ -split "="
        $Name = ($arr[0] -replace '"', '').Trim()
        $Value = ($arr[1] -replace '"', '').Trim()
        New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{Name=$Name; IP=$Value}
    }

    if ($_ -match "ip_addresses") {
        $start = $true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`regex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=net-6.0) to extract all the IP Addresses from the file. All credits on the `regex` goes to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30023010/15339544).

The following will give you an `array`, if you need them comma separated, `-join ','` will do it.

```
$file = Get-Content ./inputs.txt -Raw

[regex]::Matches(
    $file,
    '\b((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b'
).Value
```

**Note:** the `regex` will only support valid IPv4 Addresses, something like `999.2.3.4` will **not** be matched.