# IP Address regex with netmasks

Tags: regex, expression, ip-address

the format goal:
require **a.b.c.d/x** where >>

- a is 1-3 digit num btw 1-223
- b, c, and d are 1-3 digit num btw 0-255 and *required
- x is 1 or 2 digit num btw 8-32 and **the (/x) group is optional**

***here's the full regex I have now:***

```
^(((?:22[0-3]|2([0-1])?\d?|([1-9][0-9]?|1[0-9]{2}))\.)((?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?(\d{0,2}))\.){2}((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?(\d{0,2}))(\/([89]|[12]\d|3[0-2]))?),?\s?){1,50}$
```

**The problem I'm running into is: if "1.1.1." is entered (aka no 'd' group), it's passing validation. I want it to fail without the 'd' group **

here is the monstrosity broken into groups and w/ added spaces for my own sanity/readability:
// start string, full group

```
^(
```

// a group, 1-223 with "."

```
((?:22[0-3]|2([0-1])?\d?|([1-9][0-9]?|1[0-9]{2}))\.)
```

// b and c groups 0-255 with "."

```
((?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?(\d{0,2}))\.){2}
```

// d group, ends with optional netmask instead of "."
// i tried making this non-optional as a group to solve my problem.

```
((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?(\d{0,2}))
```

// netmask

```
(\/([89]|[12]\d|3[0-2]))?)
```

// allow comma separated, optional space between, up to 50 IPs

```
,?\s?){1,50}$
```

(I'm realizing now that this comma is optional so they could split with only a space. Maybe I can prevent that too).

Comment: updated version... which I think solves this `^(((22[0-3]|2([0-1])?\d?|([1-9][0-9]?|1[0-9]{2}))\.)((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|([0-9][0-9]?|1[0-9]{2}))\.){2}((25[0-5]|2([0-1])?\d?|([0-9][0-9]?|1[0-9]{2}))(\/([89]|[12]\d|3[0-2]))?),?\s?){1,50}$` << the problem was  `[01]?(\d{0,2}` in the b and c sections. they were making the whole number "optional" since one was using ? and one was allowing 0 digits.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RegEx for an IP Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890789/regex-for-an-ip-address)

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to see what your regex does if you format the pattern and add in-pattern comments.

Here is your *[current regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3yBei0/1)*:

```py
^(
  ((?:22[0-3]|2([0-1])?\d?|([1-9][0-9]?|1[0-9]{2}))\.) # a group, 1-223 with "."
   ((?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?(\d{0,2}))\.){2} # b and c groups 0-255 with "."
((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?(\d{0,2})) # d group, ends with optional netmask instead of "." // i tried making this non-optional as a group to solve my problem.
(\/([89]|[12]\d|3[0-2]))?) # netmask
,?\s?){1,50}$ # allow comma separated, optional space between, up to 50 IPs
```

**However**, this regex is not only imprecise, it also [leads to catastrophic backtracking](https://regex101.com/r/3yBei0/2) with some long non-matching strings.

Your netmask pattern is fine. It seems you had issues with creating a numeric range regex. You can always resort to online utilities that can generate these patterns for you, I wrote one and shared on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67502416/3832970).

So, a pattern for 1-223 range is `(?:[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[01][0-9]|22[0-3])` (you can manually reduce it to `(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d{2}|2[01]\d|22[0-3])`) and a pattern for 0-255 range is `(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])` (reduced to `(?:[1-9]?\d|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])`)

You can see that using these patterns fixes the issue and makes the pattern CA-resistent:

```py
^(?:
   (?:[1-9]\d?|1\d{2}|2[01]\d|22[0-3])\.         # a group, 1-223 with "."
   (?:(?:[1-9]?\d|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){2} # b and c groups 0-255 with "."
   (?:[1-9]?\d|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])          # d group, ends with optional netmask instead of "."
   (?:\/(?:[89]|[12]\d|3[0-2]))?                 # netmask
   ,?\s?                                         # allow comma separated, optional space between
){1,50}$                                         # up to 50 IPs
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3yBei0/5).

Comment: thank you wiktor this is really helpful to see it cleaned up. I realized as I was working that it could probably be significantly optimized and you did exactly that. What do you mean by CA-resistent?

Comment: @iamhill catastrophic backtracking resistent.