# regular expression search in Adobe dreamweaver

Tags: regex, search, expression, dreamweaver

I have 1000 of PHP files in an application which is developed by another programmer.
In the PHP files I would like to search - the PHP files has used any IP address or not (***.***.***.**).

I guess it is possible in dreamweaver using regular expression. I am searching for it, meanwhile if any one is familiar with that please guide me.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27960808/expression-or-reg-ex-for-java-script-or-adobe-livecycle-tools

Please help me here , i am stuck here and its urgent now.[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27960808/expression-or-reg-ex-for-java-script-or-adobe-livecycle-tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a find over all files using a regex that works for IPs.

Referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-hostname-or-ip-address), you can use the following expression (modified to remove the start/end of line anchors as the IP addresses may be inline instead of on their own line):

```
\b(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\b
```

Don't forget to check 'regular expressions' in the dreamweaver find dialog & also select all the files you want to search through.