# check hostnames and IP addresses (v4 and v6) using a single python regex?

Tags: python, regex

Is it possible to check a string with a single regex and validate it if matches valid IPv4 or IPv6 address or even a hostname with no special characters but dot (.)?

I have separate regex for IPv4 and IPv6 but how do I combine them to do the work described above?

Thanks in advance,

Dan

Comment: Just do: `(regexIPv4)|(regexIPv6)`

Comment: That's gotta be a *huge* regex, at least if it matches every valid hostname and rejects every invalid one.

Comment: Thanks Bart, but what about hostnames?

Comment: You might want to check out http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Regular-Expressions/RegexforIPv6Address.htm in conjunction with what @BartKiers said. Also, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-hostname-or-ip-address).

Comment: possible duplicate of [ip address validation in python using regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086572/ip-address-validation-in-python-using-regex)

Comment: @Niklas I want to keep the hostname one simple with only regular charatcters. I think it's more challenging to combine the separate regex without breaking the each other e.g. I don't want the hostname regex to break the ipv6 part

Comment: @StevenRumbalski That isn't a duplicate. This asks for IPv4, 6 and hostnames.

Comment: @dan: Just use alternation: `|` if you don't care about proper matching. If you do care, don't use regex for the job.

Comment: @Lattyware:  Understood.  However, between http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-hostname-or-ip-address and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/319279/how-to-validate-ip-address-in-python the question need not have been asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *could* use a single regex, but it's going to be ugly as hell. Either;

- Create separate regexes as strings, then combine them. Far more legible. Or,
- Test each regex separately. Also much clearer.

Perl-ish example:

```
if ( $foo =~ /$ipv4_re/ or $foo =~ /$ipv6_re/ or $foo =~ /$hostname_re/ ) {
    ...
}
```

Having said that, there are probably libraries in Python that will validate these things for you, and personally I'd rather rely on them.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}|                    (?# IPv4 address)
[:a-fA-F0-9]*:[:a-fA-F0-9]*:[:a-fA-F0-9.]*| (?# IPv6 address)
[-a-z0-9A-Z]+\.[-a-z0-9A-Z]*                (?# domain name)
```

Of course, you're free to substitute the individual expressions with more complex ones.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?P<ihost>\\[(?:(?:[0-9A-F]{1,4}:){6}(?:[0-9A-F]{1,4}:[0-9A-F]{1,4}|(?:(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)))|::(?:[0-9A-F]{1,4}:){5}(?:[0-9A-F]{1,4}:[0-9A-F]{1,4}|(?:(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)))|[0-9A-F]{1,4}?::(?:[0-9A-F]{1,4}:){4}(?:[0-9A-F]{1,4}:[0-9A-F]{1,4}|(?:(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)))|(?:(?:[0-9A-F]{1,4}:)?[0-9A-F]{1,4})?::(?:[0-9A-F]{1,4}:){3}(?:[0-9A-F]{1,4}:[0-9A-F]{1,4}|(?:(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)))|(?:(?:[0-9A-F]{1,4}:){,2}[0-9A-F]{1,4})?::(?:[0-9A-F]{1,4}:){2}(?:[0-9A-F]{1,4}:[0-9A-F]{1,4}|(?:(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)))|(?:(?:[0-9A-F]{1,4}:){,3}[0-9A-F]{1,4})?::(?:[0-9A-F]{1,4}:)(?:[0-9A-F]{1,4}:[0-9A-F]{1,4}|(?:(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)))|(?:(?:[0-9A-F]{1,4}:){,4}[0-9A-F]{1,4})?::(?:[0-9A-F]{1,4}:[0-9A-F]{1,4}|(?:(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)))|(?:(?:[0-9A-F]{1,4}:){,5}[0-9A-F]{1,4})?::[0-9A-F]{1,4}|(?:(?:[0-9A-F]{1,4}:){,6}[0-9A-F]{1,4})?::|v[0-9A-F]+\\.(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_.~-]|[!$&'()*+,;=]|:)+)\\]|(?:(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))|(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9._~-]|[\xa0-\ud7ff\uf900-\ufdcf\ufdf0-\uffef\U00010000-\U0001fffd\U00020000-\U0002fffd\U00030000-\U0003fffd\U00040000-\U0004fffd\U00050000-\U0005fffd\U00060000-\U0006fffd\U00070000-\U0007fffd\U00080000-\U0008fffd\U00090000-\U0009fffd\U000a0000-\U000afffd\U000b0000-\U000bfffd\U000c0000-\U000cfffd\U000d0000-\U000dfffd\U000e1000-\U000efffd])|%[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]|[!$&'()*+,;=])*)
```

(from [rfc3987](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/rfc3987))