# Extracting integer values from a string on Python

Tags: string, python-2.7, shell, integer

I've been through every post I could find on the subject and nothing have answered my problem;

This is the code:
`output = 'Scan results for BrainS (192.168.43.111) 
           Scan results for Slave (192.168.43.107)
           Scan results for SlaveSmall (192.168.43.242)'
while (True)
      if output[i].isdigit():       # i has initial value of 15, j=0
           f[j]=output[i]
           j+=1
           i+=1
      elsif(i == len(output)):
           break
      else:
           i+=1
           continue`

Print:
`>>>f
['1','9','2','1','6','8','4','3','1','1','1','0','0','0']`

As you can see I'm trying to extract the IP as it is with dots(in this code I didnt try to extract the dots but only the numbers),
I cant figure out how do get the string I want exactly as it is:
***f = 192.168.43.111***

Any suggestions? better commands?

Comment: Regex is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086572/ip-address-validation-in-python-using-regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For multiple pairs of parenthesis in the string I think it is best to use a regex like so:

```
import re

output = '''Scan results for BrainS (192.168.43.111) 
            Scan results for Slave (192.168.43.107)
            Scan results for SlaveSmall (192.168.43.242)'''

f = re.findall(r'\(([^()]+)\)',output)
>>>['192.168.43.111', '192.168.43.107', '192.168.43.242']
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/Ewjd/1)

Comment: wow thanks a lot works like a charm,how about if there were several lines like this one? but different IP's. then i'd have a few "(" & ")" , is there a solution to that?

Comment: Edit your question to show these other lines. The above code only works if there is only one pair of parenthesis in the string.

Comment: I've just edited it, I've added the actual output I get, I tried to simplify it before. I hope this can help you understand my question better.

Comment: That should work @eyal360 , the earlier answer only makes sense for one pair of parenthesis :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, this code will do the job!

```
output = 'My computer IP is = (192.168.43.111) and yours not.'
ip=[]
ip_flag = False

for x in output:
    if x == '(':
        ip_flag = True
        continue
    if ip_flag:
        if x != ')':
            if x != '.': # remove this line of you want the dots
                ip.append(x)
        else:
            break
print(ip)
theIp="" 
for i in ip: 
    theIp+=i
```

Comment: This answer actually gave me the ['1','9','2',...] formation that I didnt want in the first place, but it works good.

Comment: @eyal360 if you want the dots remove this line `if x != '.':`
if you want a string just add a loop at the end like this 
`theIp=""
for i in ip:
theIp+=i`
done

Comment: you can't see it because im under 15 Rep , but you got it, its just not shown. [link]https://s30.postimg.org/8ci2mzhfl/Upvote.jpg