# Is there a way to recognise an IP address or a MAC address in a list?

Tags: python

I have a list containing the data of a command. There is always 3 elements in this list :

```
> print (command)
['ip1', 'mac1', 'name1']
```

Sometime the 3rd element expand because the name of the equipment is using multiple word.

```
> print (command[2]) # name 1
Desk
```

or

```
> print (command[2]) # name 1
Living Room
```

But it can also expand because it containing another result :

```
> print (command)
['ip1', 'mac1', 'name 1 ip2 mac2 name2']
```

When i split the third element by blank space, the position of ip2 and mac2 in the new list can change :

```
> array = command[2].split()
> print (array)
['Desk', '192.168.1.2', 'aa:bb:cc:01:02:03', 'Kitchen']
['Living', 'Room', '192.168.1.10', 'dd:ee:ff:77:88:99', 'Kitchen']
```

I would like to get ip2 and mac2 from the third element, but i dont know how to search / recognise a string pattern. In bash i would use '#' to replace the changing characters of the adresses and try to match with a if, while i loop through the new list. But in python i can't do #.#.#.# for the ip and the address.

Comment: This sound like the source of the list should be fixed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086572/ip-address-validation-in-python-using-regex

Comment: there is [ipaddress module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) as well as Unix filename pattern matching [fnmatch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html) built in.

Comment: How can `print (command[2])` print two different things. You question makes little sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are having issues with recognizing string patters I would personally be tempted to just use [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) (regex). There's examples for search patters for mac and ip adresses, but you can of course write your own regex as well. To use it you do need to import the `re` module.

An easy way to match a ip adress would be `((?:\d+\.){3}\d+)`  and be similar to `#.#.#.#`.

Here's how it works:

```
?: At the beginning of the () is to indicate a non capturing group (normally () are used for groups, but in this case I just want to use it to structure my regex)
\d is any digit (0-9)
+ means one or more of them
\. is just a dot (the \ is to escape it)
{3} means repeat the non capturing group 3 times
\d+ is for the last digits.
```

For reference some more sophisticated approaches for MAC adresses [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-validate-mac-address-using-regular-expression/).

Good luck.