# How to validate IP address using Robot Framework

Tags: python, selenium, user-interface, robotframework

**How to validate IP address using Robot Framework**

Example: **192.168.101.12**

*Conditions:*

1. Number of characters
2. String should not exceed 15 characters
3. Allow only numeric characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Builtin library has a keyword for matching regexes. You can use [Should Match Regexp](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Should%20Match%20Regexp) to validate the ip. Here is an example I made with a regexp from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086572/ip-address-validation-in-python-using-regex)

```
***Variables***
${correct_ip}    192.168.101.12
${false_ip}      999.999.999.999
${ip_regexp}      ^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$
*** Test Cases ***  
test 
    Should Match Regexp    ${correct_ip}    ${ip_regexp}
    Should Not Match Regexp    ${false_ip}    ${ip_regexp}
```

Comment: #jiri janous  ,   it was fine..  for input alpha numeric validation using robot framework             can you please try to help    ex: input:32003        valid         input 2: 200F9  INVALID      INPUT3:   32990237449213040129348091283408719328409439184          LENGTH<=32

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex to validate the ips.

```
import re

def isValidIp(ip):
    pattern = "((\d{1,3}).(\d{1,3}).(\d{1,3}).(\d{1,3}))"

    if re.match(pattern, ip):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

test:

```
test = ["123.123.123","randomstring","123.a54.12","1234.12.1111"]

for item in test:
    print(isValidIp(item))

True
False
False
True
```

Comment: where i can place this robot code                                                                                                                                     settings      or      variables      or      test cases     or      keywords