# Is there a simple way in ruby to call next word in a string?

Tags: ruby, string, parsing, sinatra, loops

Long story short I am checking a rather lengthy error log. I would like to find and parse the ip address associated with each error.

example I want to parse

client: 12.345.678.910

```
def check_file( file, string )
  File.open( file ) do |io|
    io.each do |line|
      result << parse_ip( line ) if line.include? string
    end
  end
  result
end

def parse_ip( flag )
  flag = flag.split.find_all{|word| /^client:.+/.match word}
  ip = flag. # need to grab ip here
  ip
end
```

Is there a simple way to get next word?

I am just not sure how to grab the characters following "client:"

Any assistance is appreciated.

EDIT: syntax error

Comment: There's a regexp for IPv4 addresses in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/106223/215168) that should be of some use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to do it.  For your example, you could extract the ip with a single regexp capture:

```
def parse_ip( flag )
  m = /\bclient:\s*([\d\.]+)/.match flag
  m && m[1]
end
```

If you really prefer to tokenize with split for other reasons, you can use [Enumerable#drop_while](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-drop_while) to scan to the key, then index to the next token:

```
def parse_ip( flag )
  flag.split.drop_while{|token| token !~ /^client:/}[1]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"client: 12.345.678.910"[/client:\s*(.*?)\s*$/, 1]
 => "12.345.678.910"
```