# Parsing IP addresses for DNS server using RegEx

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

```
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.204.127.11
                                    10.207.2.50
                                    10.200.10.6
```

I'm trying to build a RegEx to parse out N number of IP addresses.

**I understand there is an allegedly duplicate post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-hostname-or-ip-address), but it is not working with the following RegEx:**
**http://regexr.com?321nu**

`^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$`

p.s. sorry, a colleague of mine started this post on my account for me while I was away. I suppose I've added more information here.  Feel free to unbury me.

Comment: What platform/language? Unix/bash? Perl? Python?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular expression to match hostname or IP Address?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-hostname-or-ip-address)

Comment: @Qiau, this is in HP Operations Manager which is compatible with Perl and Java type RegEx.  This is not tagged with either because I didn't want SO'ers responding in Java or Perl similiar to one of my previous questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)` ?

As some numbers should not be allowed, better but not perfect pattern would be:

```
(1[0-9]{0,2}|2[0-9]{0,1}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]|[3-9][0-9]?)(\.(0|1[0-9]{0,2}|2[0-9]{0,1}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]|[3-9][0-9]?)){3}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have **exactly three** IP addresses (see at [Regexr](http://regexr.com?320p6)) use `\1`,`\2` and `\3` from this regex:

```
^\D*(.*)\s*(.*)\s*(.*)$
```

If you have **1 to 3** IP addresses (see at [Regexr](http://regexr.com?320p6)) use `\1`,`\2` and `\3` from this regex (check if `\2` and `\3` exist before use):

```
^\D*(?:(.*)(?:\s*(.*)(?:\s*(.*))?)?)$
```