# Something wrong with pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I have simple check

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var pattern = /^[\.\/\w]$/;

    $('input[type="submit"]').click(function(){
        for (var i = 2; i < $('input[name="input_data[]"]').length; i++) {
            if(!pattern.test($('input:eq('+i+')').val())){
                console.log(pattern.test($('input:eq('+i+')').val()));
                console.log($('input:eq('+i+')').val());
                alert('Please doublecheck info.')
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

`input:eq('+i+').val()` is array of different file paths like `/var/www/logs/log1`, but something is wrong in `pattern` - sometime it fires just on good path, sometime skips `/var/www/logs/log'` (at the end ')

Example of list that should be passed:

> /var/www/logs/log 
> /var/www/logs/log1
>  /var/www/logs/log2
>   192.168.1.1 
> 200

Comment: See also this SO [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/106179/363573)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match any valid path or just an IP :

> /^([\/\w.]+|(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]).){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]))$/

```
/var/www/logs/log  => OK
/var/www/logs/log2 => OK
/var/www/logs/log' => NOK
/a/small/path/     => OK
192.1.168.23       => OK
```

Comment: Can you send a list of paths and point out how the pattern should react on them in your question ?

Comment: Possible:
/var/www/logs/log
/var/www/logs/log1
/var/www/logs/log2
192.168.1.1
200