# PHP if IP or Domain detect function

Tags: php

Is there a way to detect if a string is a Ip or Domain using php, example below.

```
$string = "http://192.168.0.0";
$string = "http://example.com";
```

So if the string is a IP the script/function will do something if it detects it as Domain it will do something else.

Thank you

Comment: This is typically done using regular expressions. You will find millions of examples on google.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can test it simply like this:

```
$isIP = (bool)ip2long($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

The function [ip2long](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php) will return `false` is host is not a valid IP address like domain name. The benefit of using `ip2long` function is that it also validates provided IP address. So for example address is 4.4.4.756 will give you false.

So to test a given string you can do:

```
$string = "http://192.168.0.0";
$parts = parse_url($string);
$isIP = (bool)ip2long($parts['host']);
```

Answer (score 2):

You also may compare HTTP_HOST and SERVER_ADDR.
For IP v6 you should also trim square brackets on HTTP_HOST.

```
$isIP = @($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] === trim($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], '[]'));
```

seems to be more efficient than regex, but not sure if ip2long aproach would be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions.

Here you can find example:

[Regular expression to match DNS hostname or IP Address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-hostname-or-ip-address)

Code / regex patterns:

```
ValidIpAddressRegex = "^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$";

ValidHostnameRegex = "^(([a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$";
```

How to use regex in php:

[preg-match manual at php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Answer (score 0):

You have the regular expressions on that SO question: [Regular expression to match DNS hostname or IP Address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-hostname-or-ip-address)

And you will need to use the PHP function: [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-match.php)