# Is it a valid Regular expression for IP address

Tags: ruby, regex

Is this a valid regular expression for IP-addresses?

```
^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-5]{2}|0{2}|0{3})\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-5]{2}|0{2}|0{3})$
```

Comment: Please share a bit more information: what do you want to achieve with the regex? Must it extract certain blocks? Should it simply validate? Must it validate only a certain range? Also consider sharing a few example IP-adresses where you want to let the regex loose on.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html

Comment: Hi May be this solution on Stackoverflow can help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-hostname-or-ip-address

Comment: Hi May be this solution on Stackoverflow can help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-hostname-or-ip-address

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not correct : in the first part ((....){3}) : the last 2[0-5]{2} will allow 201, 254, etc, but not 239, etc (ie, last digit >5)

Now, a 5 seconds search in a search engine gave me this url : http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/318-how-to-match-ipv4-addresses-with-regular-expressions/

And as @Sigardave pointed out, a more "local" solution ^^ (ie, in the same area of the Internet) : [Regular expression to match DNS hostname or IP Address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-hostname-or-ip-address)

Answer (score 2):

This is how [IPAddr](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/ipaddr/rdoc/IPAddr.html) in standard lib does it:

```
# Returns +true+ if +addr+ is a valid IPv4 address.
def valid_v4?(addr)
  if /\A(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\Z/ =~ addr
    return $~.captures.all? {|i| i.to_i < 256}
  end
  return false
end
```

Comment: Link to where you see that in the source?