# Regex for getting IP address from email header

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regular expression to match DNS hostname or IP Address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-hostname-or-ip-address)

I need regular expression to get the IP address from email header. There are lot's of header under received Section.

But I want to read ipaddress only from the line which have pattern like this.

```
Received: from unknown 124.253.91.178 by rediffmail.com via HTTP; 11 Jan 2013 10:10:35 -0000
```

I tried the below regex, But it returns all the ip address of email header text.

```
 preg_match_all("/\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/", $this->email, $matches);
```

I want to match  `Received:` and `from` word and ip Address in the one line. Ip address can be IPv6 or IPv4

Answer (score 1):

You can try with following regex:

```
/^Received: .*?(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}))/
```

Regex for both IPv4 and IPv6:

```
/^Received: .*?((?:\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})|([a-z0-9]{4}(?::[a-z0-9]{4}){7}))/
```

Comment: Thanks, What if ip address is IPV6 Like this , 2001:0db8:85a3:0042:1000:8a2e:0370:7334

Comment: I got this error preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses at offset

Comment: But it's not returning Ip address, print_r($matches) OUTPUT:  `array(3) { [0]=> array(0) { } [1]=> array(0) { } [2]=> array(0) { } }`