# Need to accurately write RegEx query

Tags: c#, .net, regex, powershell

I have a piece of html code that I extracted:

```
Server Address</span></td><td    ><span  class="hpPageText" >hostname0403.domain.tld</span></td><
```

From this string, I am trying to extract the fqdn (hostname0403.domain.tld). I figured I would use the following logic:

1. begins with >, ends with <
2. must include at least 1 period (dot).
3. must include either all numbers, all letters, or a combination of both.

What I am hoping to end up with is ">hostname0403.domain.tld<" and from there I can strip off the ><. This is the reg that I have so far, which works, but I don't think it is accurate:

```
$reg = ">[\w\.]+<"
```

I am very new to regex and while this does work, i'm not sure if it is fail safe. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just for the record: Parsing HTML with RegEx is not recommended.
But to help you, it is important which parts of that HTML-Stuff change an which parts dont't.

Comment: To echo what @DasKrümelmonster said: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) as to why you shouldn't use regex to parse HTML in general.

Comment: Mybe an overkill for your purpose but I would have a go at http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

The regex pattern needs some work.  For instance, there could be whitespace before and/or after the hostname.  And a hostname can contain '-' characters.  You can handle the whitespace like so:

```
'>\s*(..hostname regex)\s*<'
```

For a better hostname regex, see this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-hostname-or-ip-address) answer.  Here's how you would modify that regex to suit your needs:

```
$str = 'Server Address</span></td><td    ><span  class="hpPageText" >hostname0403.domain.tld</span></td><'
$ValidHostnameRegex = ">\s*((?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*(?:[A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9]))\s*<"
$str -match $ValidHostnameRegex
$matches[1]
```

Outputs:

```
hostname-0403.domain.tld
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following (as a bonus, the Regex excludes the > and < for you):

```
        string source = @"Server Address</span></td><td    ><span  class=""hpPageText"" >hostname0403.domain.tld</span></td><";
        Regex r = new Regex(@"(?<=\>)(([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])(?=\<)");

        string fqdn = "";
        Match fqdnMatch = r.Match(source);
        if (fqdnMatch.Success)
        {
            fqdn = fqdnMatch.Value;
        }
```

Comment: thx. when i use your regex, i get back 4 matches: tld, domain, domain., and the fqdn. I would like it to return only 1 - the fqdn.

Comment: If you want to eliminate the groups, you could use this instead:
    "(?<=\>)(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*(?:[A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])(?=\<)"
It simply hides the groups.  However, either way only one "Value" is created.