# How to extract IP from following string

Tags: regex, perl

```
$string  > show box detail
2 boxes:
1) Box ID: 1
       IP:                  127.0.0.1*
Interface:           1/1
 Priority:            31
```

How to extract IP from above string withc additional check for * ?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-hostname-or-ip-address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since that looks like a file, my first assumption is that you want a one-liner:

```
perl -anlwe 'if ($F[0] eq "IP:") { print $F[1] }' input.txt
```

Otherwise, I would suggest a soft regex such as:

```
if ($foo =~ /IP:\s*(\S+)/) { 
    $ip = $1;
}
```

Comment: how to get rid of * if its present ?

Comment: Perhaps `tr/*//d`? Or `s/\**$//g`. A pretty basic perl question, which makes me suspect you don't know any perl at all.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only have one thing that looks like an ip, you can just use this regex:

```
(?:([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])
```

This is what it looks like on [Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/?re=%28%3F%3A%28%5B0-9%5D%7C%5B1-9%5D%5B0-9%5D%7C1%5B0-9%5D%7B2%7D%7C2%5B0-4%5D%5B0-9%5D%7C25%5B0-5%5D%29%5C.%29%7B3%7D%28%5B0-9%5D%7C%5B1-9%5D%5B0-9%5D%7C1%5B0-9%5D%7B2%7D%7C2%5B0-4%5D%5B0-9%5D%7C25%5B0-5%5D%29&str=127.0.0.1).

Comment: +1 This is actually more specific than the regex I posted (which only looked for digits not specific 0-255 values). I was going for quick and dirty :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [Regexp::Common](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Regexp%3a%3aCommon%3a%3anet):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.012;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Regexp::Common qw( net );

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    my @ips = ($line =~ /($RE{net}{IPv4})/g)
        or next;
    say @ips;
}

__DATA__
$string  > show box detail
2 boxes:
1) Box ID: 1
       IP:                  127.0.0.1*
Interface:           1/1
 Priority:            31
2) Box ID: 2
       IP:                  10.10.1.1
Interface:           1/1
 Priority:            31
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to match (shown with optional *)

```
((\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\*?)
```

Comment: This is incorrect. It will match, say, `602.0.3.5`, which is not a valid ipv4 address. However, I imagine for the OP's use, it's good enough.

Comment: @SergiuToarca Yes I understand that, but since this string is likely to only be populated with valid IP addresses, I presented this as a quick and dirty solution.  It seems the interest was more in extraction of the value that is was in validation of the value.

Comment: You are right @MikeBrant :) I am looking on extraction part only