# Match IP and Port number withing parantheses

Tags: regex

I am trying to fetch the IP addr and Port no separately from a given string.

```
STRING: 
(10.10.2.5:1567)
```

I need the O/P as

```
10.10.2.5
1567
```

I am new to RegEx and the pattern I am using is

```
\(([\d.]+):\d+\).*
```

This one seems to pick `10.10.2.5` but fails to pick the `1567`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this regular expression:

```
\(([\d.]+):(\d+)\).*
```

Its is essentially the same regex as yours with the following 2 changes:

1. Escape the parenthesis "(" and ").
2. Add second capture group to get the port number.

So `$1` will have the IP address and `$2` will have the port number.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern

```
\d+[.]\d+[.]\d+[.]\d+(:\d+)?
```

Answer (score 0):

You are capturing IP address with the first group

```
([\d.]+)
```

but not the port. You need another pair of parenthesis to define the second group

```
\(([\d.]+):([\d]+)\).*
```

Notice that the first group is also too generic: it will accept any mix of digits and dots:

```
23424....2342423
```

See [Regular expression to match DNS hostname or IP Address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-hostname-or-ip-address) for a more strict expression

Comment: This works Perfect ! Thank you Matteo. Good explanation too.Much appreciate for a timely response :-)