# simple regex for a series of numbers and dots. N{3}.N{3}.N{3}.N{3}

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, regex, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP.NET 4.0 MVC app in C# and I need to create a regex that will match N{3}.N{3}.N{3}.{N{3} where N{3} is any 1, 2, or 3 digits(0-9) e.g.

```
    1.1.1.1
    111.111.111.111
    1.111.111.1
```

I have tried

```
    @"^[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}$"
```

but this matches things I don't want it to like

```
    111.1.1
    1111.1.1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: dot is a wildcard so you need to escape it like Sean said.

Comment: Are you trying to match an IP address?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `.` in a regular expression means "any character."  Therefore if you want to match a literal `.` you need to escape it, as shown below:

```
@"^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$"
```

Comment: +1. Should fix it. The regex can probably be shortened to something like `^\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3}$`

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to match an IP address, there are some great RexEx expressions here:

[Regular expression to match DNS hostname or IP Address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-hostname-or-ip-address)