# IP and hostname detection

Tags: java, regex, dns

I know basics of java but I am not too experienced with regex or patterns, so please excuse me if im asking something super simple..
Im writing a method that detects IP addresses and hostnames. I used the regex from this answere [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-hostname-or-ip-address). The problem I am encountering though is that sentences without symbols are counted as host names

Heres my code:

```
    Pattern validHostname = Pattern.compile("^(([a-z]|[a-z][a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]).)*([a-z]|[a-z][a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])$",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Pattern validIpAddress = Pattern.compile("^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])([:]\\d\\d*\\d*\\d*\\d*)*$",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    String msg = c.getMessage();
    boolean found=false;

    //Randomly picks from a list to replace the detected ip/hostname
    int rand=(int)(Math.random()*whitelisted.size());
    String replace=whitelisted.get(rand);

    Matcher matchIP = validIpAddress.matcher(msg);
    Matcher matchHost = validHostname.matcher(msg);

    while(matchIP.find()){
        if(adreplace)
            msg=msg.replace(matchIP.group(),replace);
        else
            msg=msg.replace(matchIP.group(),"");

        found=true;
        c.setMessage(msg);
    }
    while(matchHost.find()){
        if(adreplace)
            msg=msg.replace(matchHost.group(),replace);
        else
            msg=msg.replace(matchHost.group(),"");

        found=true;
        c.setMessage(msg);
    }
    return c;
```

Comment: Can you give some example?

Comment: Can you provide several example of the input (some values for `msg`)?

Comment: An example message would be: Hello, come visit my website www.google.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Description

Without sample text and desired output, I'll try my best to answer your question.

I would rewrite you host name expression like this:

**A:** `^(?:[a-z][a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9](?=\.[a-z]|$)\.?)+$` will allow single word names like `abcdefg`

**B:** `^(?=(?:.*?\.){2})(?:[a-z][a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9](?=\.[a-z]|$)\.?)+$` requires the string to contain at least two period like `abc.defg.com`. This will not allow a period to appear at the beginning or end, or sequential periods. The number inside the lookahead `{2}` describes the minimum number of dots which must appear. You can change this number as you see fit.

[image]

- `^` match the start of the string anchor
- `(?:` start non-capture group improves performance
- `[a-z][a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]` match text, taken from your original expression
- `(?=\.[a-z]|$)` look ahead to see if the next character is a dot followed by an a-z character, or the end of the string
- `\.?` consume a single dot if it exists
- `)` close the capture group
- `+` require the contents of the capture group to exist 1 or more times
- `$` match the end of the string anchor

Host names:
[**A** Allows host name without dots](http://www.rubular.com/r/tDZIV5KHHQ)
[**B** Requires host name to have a dot](http://www.rubular.com/r/HqR6r7g91Y)

[Live Demo with a sentence with no symbols](http://www.rubular.com/r/0XYWS2v5P7)

I would also rewrite the IP expression

`^(?:(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?::\d*)?$`

The major differences here are that I:

- removed the multiple \d* from the end because expression `\d*\d*\d*\d*\d*\d*` is equivalent to `\d*`
- changed the character class `[:]` to a single character `:`
- I turned the capture groups `(`...`)` into non-capture groups `(?`...`)` which performs a little better.

Comment: This helps so much! The only thing I can spot that's off is that the regex catches singular words ex."hello" with no special charcters.

Comment: What are your requirements for a host name? Should it be a FQDN which must contain a period?

Comment: The host name should at least have "SiteName.com" in it, but things like www. I would like to count as well. And yes just periods. Im not really concerned about ipv6