# How to match everything inside the first pair of square brackets

Tags: regex, sieve-language

I'm trying to create a [regular expression](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-murchison-sieve-regex-08) in [sieve](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5228). The implementation of sieve that I'm using is [Dovecot Pigeonhole](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Pigeonhole/Sieve)

I'm subscribed to github project updates and I receive emails from github with the subject in the format that looks like this:

> Re: [Opserver] Create issues on Jira from Exception details page (#77)

There is a project name in square bracket included in the subject line. Here is the relevant part of my sieve script:

```
if address "From" "notifications@github.com" {
  if header :regex "subject" "\\[(.*)\\]" {
      set :lower :upperfirst "repository" "${1}";
      fileinto :create "Subscribtions.GitHub.${repository}"; stop;
  } else {
      fileinto :create "Subscribtions.GitHub"; stop;
  }
}
```

As you can see from the above, I'm moving the messages to appropriate project IMAP folders. So the message with the subject above will end up in `Subscribtions.Github.Opserver`

Unfortunately, there is one small problem with this script. If someone adds square brackets in the title of their github issue, the filter breaks. For example if the subject is:

> [Project] [Please look at it] - very weird issue

The above filter will move the message to folder `Subscribtions.Github.Project] [please look at it` which is completely undesirable. I'd like it to be moved to `Subscribtions.Github.Project` anyway.

This happens because by default regular expressions are greedy. So they match the longest possible match. However when I try to fix it the usual way changing `"\\[(.*)\\]"` to `"\\[(.*?)\\]"` nothing seems to change.

How do I write this regular expression so that it acts as desired?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is to change `"\\[(.*)\\]"` to `"\\[([^]]*)\\]"`.

By reading [regex spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-murchison-sieve-regex-08) linked in the question we disvover that [POSIX regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended) are used. Unfortunately those [do not support non-greedy matches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20241622/284111).

However there is a work around in this particular case, given above.