# Regular Expression to match IP address from SNMP walk output

Tags: regex, snmp

The output of my snmpwalk looks like this:

```
iso.3.6.1.2.1.4.20.1.2.10.0.1.2
```

The last four digits (in bold) are always an IP address. I cannot seem to create a regex that will give me just the IP address, ie `10.0.1.2`

Any help is greatly appreciated! I suck at regex so if an explanation could be included, that would really help.

Comment: Please show what you've tried, we're not here to do your work for you.

Comment: I started with this which ends up giving me just the last digit. /.([^.]+)$/

Comment: Sorry, the ** were an attempt to bold the text I am looking for. They are not actually part of the snmp output.

Comment: Please update your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just repeat it four times:

```
/(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)$/
```

or shorter:

```
/(\d+(\.\d+){3})$/
```

See how it performs at [Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/gE8aL6)

Comment: +1 simple = best. I would not even show the long version.

Answer (score 2):

You can use match your ip address by regex

```
MatchIpAddressRegex = "^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$";
```

Take a look at: http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/318-how-to-match-ipv4-addresses-with-regular-expressions/

[Regular expression to match DNS hostname or IP Address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-hostname-or-ip-address)

http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html