# validate host names and IP addresses with single regex

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

Trying to combine two regexes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/106179/791406) to validate host names and IP addresses in a single statement.

I've got them working separately, but when combining using `|`, things get screwy, matching fragments of host names and ips, not whole valid patterns, which is not what I want. I need a single regex, using the host name and IP patterns below, to match either host or IP addresses.

I've provided scratch pads where I've tested each pattern; the last one is my attempt at combining them, with examples illustrating regex matching invalid fragments.

[regex: Host Names](http://regex101.com/r/xB5yP9)

```
^((([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9]))$
```

[regex: IP Address](http://regex101.com/r/aL2mO4)

```
^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3})$
```

[regex: Host name and IPs](http://regex101.com/r/hN3nX0) (not working)

```
^((([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9]))|((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3})$
```

Comment: Well? Show us what you've got. Please include your regex in your question, not in some off-site resource.

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. I'd have expected someone with 4800 reputation to know this.

Comment: Combine them by `\(regex1\)\|\(regex2\)`. Backslashes may or may not be required depending on your language.

Comment: @GregHewgill I provided regex links to what I've been trying, the combined regex reflects my attempts, combining parentheses and using `|`, I'm not well versed with regex, my apologies if that was not enough.

Comment: @MikeW The regex patterns are quite long, so I chose to provide links to scratch pads where I've been testing them, all of which are working examples, illustrating the problem, so I'm not sure what you're ticked about.

Comment: @raffian You've provided links. If the links disappear, because you delete your samples or for some other reason, your question becomes meaningless.

Comment: @MikeW That's a good point, but SO has 1000's of questions with jsFiddle links and not much else; I'll update the question, nonetheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a precedence issue. When you wrote

```
^(regex1)|(regex2)$
```

It was interpreted as

```
(^(regex1))|((regex2)$)
```

So any line starting with a valid hostname or ending in an IP address matched ok. A solution is to do

```
^regex1$|^regex2$
```

Which comes out as:

```
^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3})$|^((([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9]))$
```

Comment: +1 for the explanation, I was under the impression `^` and `$` to delimiters could not be used more than once.

Comment: Minor issue with this: the combined regex is matching `1`, `1.2`, and `1.2.3` IP patterns; I've been playing with it here,  http://regex101.com/r/zC2eZ0, can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: @raffian, Actually it's matching them as hostnames. You should fix your hostname regex to not accept anything starting with a number.

Comment: simple change, http://regex101.com/r/mU6bE3, thx again