# check if IP address exist in URL return something else return something

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I check whether the IP address exist in URL by using Python? 
Is there any function that can be used to check the IP address? 
For example:data 1 & data 2 got the IP then will return 1, while data 3 will return 0

```
data =['http://95.154.196.187/broser/6716804bc5a91f707a34479012dad47c/',
       'http://95.154.196.187/broser/',
       'http://paypal.com.cgi-bin-websc5.b4d80a13c0a2116480.ee0r-cmd-login-submit-dispatch-']

def IP_exist(data):
    for b in data:
        containsdigit = any(a.isdigit() for a in b)
        if containsdigit:
            print("1")
        else:
            print("0")
```

Comment: A particular IP address, or any IP address? Anywhere in the URL or in the host part? I.e. should http://google.com/search?q=127.0.0.1 match? What about http://me:95.154.196.187@localhost/? (StackOverflow displays these without the `http://` part and I'm too lazy to work around that.)

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match(r'http://\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/.*', 'http://95.154.196.187/broser/6716804bc5a91f707a34479012dad47c/')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f4412043440>
>>> re.match(r'http://\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/.*', 'http://paypal.com.cgi-bin-websc5.b4d80a13c0a2116480.ee0r-cmd-login-submit-dispatch-')
>>>
```

For a more fine grained regex look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-hostname-or-ip-address).

Comment: what does the "<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x02FEF758>" means?
if I want data 1 & data 2 got the IP then will return 1, while data 3 will return 0

Comment: @user3340270 It means a match has been found and it's returning the match. If nothing matches, it returns None, as shown in the fourth line.

Comment: @user3340270, see the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure the IP is correct you could extract it from the url using a regex as suggested in the other answer and then to validate you could use [netaddr](https://netaddr.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) it is fairly simple to use.

```
from netaddr import IP, AddrFormatError
ip = extract_ip_from_url(url)
try:
  IP(ip)
  return True
except AddrFormatError:
  return False
```