# Use Regex to find an IP

Tags: c#, regex, ip, ping

I made this application that pings a hostname, but I need to grab the IP it used during the ping command and store it in a string. I have the output of the ping command stored in another string. How can I use Regex to grab the IP from the results and store it in a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For different languages and platforms, pick one from here. . .

http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/318-how-to-match-ipv4-addresses-with-regular-expressions/

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
 ValidIpAddressRegex = "^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$";

 ValidHostnameRegex = "^(([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$";
```

Comment: please refer the link <http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html> they have good explanation for that.

Comment: Refered Stack Overflow link <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-hostname-or-ip-address>